# Replace tabs with spaces in vim

Tags: vim, vi

I would like to convert tab to spaces in gVim. I added the following line to my `_vimrc`:

```
set tabstop=2
```

It works to stop at two spaces but it still looks like one tab key is inserted (I tried to use the h key to count spaces afterwards).

I'm not sure what should I do to make gVim convert tabs to spaces?

Comment: Personally, I'd find tabstop=2 too small an indent; I use ts=4, and understand why people (such as the Linux kernel team) use ts=8 (and they don't use expandtab - I do).

Comment: Is there a way to convert spaces to tabs inside vim?

Comment: @cwd replacing the spaces with tab character ( `^I` which come from `Ctrl-v` then `Tab` ) would works, for example if your current tabs is 4 spaces: `:%s/    /^I/g`

Answer (score 520, accepted):

IIRC, something like:

```
set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab
```

should do the trick. If you already have tabs, then follow it up with a nice global RE to replace them with double spaces.

If you already have tabs you want to replace,

```
:retab
```

Comment: Oops, that's ":%!expand -t2"

Comment: or you can just use :retab

Comment: what if i want to save it with spaces ? right now when I :wq and open the file again i am back to tabs

Comment: @Gorkem put these commands into your .vimrc, so that vim uses those settings every session

Comment: What this all means, is [nicely explained on the Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces).

Comment: How can i make this `set` constant, so this change saves every time i start vim?

Comment: Open a file and type `:retab` to fix all existing tabs.

Comment: I needed this one rather than the top answer

Answer (score 959):

Once you've got expandtab on as per the other answers, the extremely convenient way to convert existing files according to your new settings is:

```
:retab
```

It will work on the current buffer.

Comment: but how can we make retab ask confirmation of each occurrence of TAB?

Comment: And being Vim, it works on visually selected regions too :)

Comment: Thanks for teach me a new thing. I've use the tedious `:%s/\t/  /g` for years before seeing your comment.

Comment: You can even do `:args retab | w` to do to all files opened on the command line, e.g., `vim *.txt`.

Comment: Does anyone know which version of vim has :retab? My 7.3.322 doesn't.

Comment: @hmmm Vim 7.4 (patches 1-160) has this command. Maybe your system is too old.

Comment: This works great!  Just not as I expect it to.   I've added expandtab, smarttab, autotab (among others) to my ~/.vimrc.   Am relatively to to vi/vim as well.   When I add new text to a file that I need tab'd over and replace tabs with spaces, I have to run expandtab & retab EVERY TIME I add or manipulate text that has new tabs present.   I was thinking that since they had been configured, when I saved the file, they would be AUTO-MAGICALLY run for me.

Comment: `:%s/\t/    /g` does the same thing

Comment: For me `:%s/\t/    /g` only worked! Got this issue for the first time today and tomorrow is my CKAD :(

Answer (score 143):

Try

```
set expandtab
```

for soft tabs.

To fix pre-existing tabs:

```
:%s/\t/  /g
```

I used two spaces since you already set your tabstop to 2 spaces.

Comment: That fix up will insert two spaces where only one is required.

Comment: instead of doing the substitution, you can do what Nick suggested above - ie retab. That will retab all your existing tabs as the number of spaces set in your tabstop.

Comment: Awesome tip! Vim showed me a perfectly idented file while **cat** (linux cmd) showed irregular identation. I just changed the 2 spaces to 4 as I use in Vim `set ts = 4`.

Answer (score 81):

*This worked for me:*

you can see tabs with first doing this:

```
:set list
```

then to make it possible to replace tabs then do this:

```
:set expandtab
```

then

```
:retab
```

now all tabs have been replaced with spaces 
you can then go back to normal viewing like this :

```
:set nolist
```

Comment: `:set list` is just beautiful.

Answer (score 50):

`gg=G` will reindent the entire file and removes most if not all the tabs I get in files from co-workers.

Comment: does it replace tabs with spaces?

Comment: Awesome! Worked for me as well.

Comment: Can you explain what gg=G do? this did exactly what i was looking for. I have html on sublime and when i pasted it in vim, it was madly indented. This now looks clean.

Comment: @jes516 `gg` moves your cursor to the beginning of the buffer.  `=` is format, and takes a movement command.  `G` moves your cursor the end of the buffer, so it tells vim to format from the beginning to the end of your current buffer.

Answer (score 47):

Add following lines to your .vimrc

```
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
map <F2> :retab <CR> :wq! <CR>
```

Open a file in vim and press F2
The tabs will be converted to 4 spaces and file will be saved automatically.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that the `q` will close the current buffer of the file as well. This may or may not be desired.

Answer (score 20):

This got it working for me:

```
:set tabstop=2 shiftwidth=2 expandtab | retab
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on :retab. I added that to the accepted answer so no one misses on that important piece :-)

Answer (score 17):

If you want to keep your `\t` equal to 8 spaces then consider setting:

```
   set softtabstop=2 tabstop=8 shiftwidth=2
```

This will give you two spaces per `<TAB>` press, but actual `\t` in your code will still be viewed as 8 characters.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `softtabstop`, one of the killer features, I think.

Answer (score 4):

This article has an excellent vimrc script for handling tabs+spaces, and converting in between them.

> These commands are provided:
>
> **Space2Tab**  Convert spaces to tabs, only in indents.
>
> **Tab2Space**  Convert tabs to spaces, only in indents.
>
> **RetabIndent**    Execute Space2Tab (if 'expandtab' is set), or Tab2Space (otherwise).
>
> Each command accepts an argument that specifies the number of spaces in a tab column. By default, the 'tabstop' setting is used.

Source: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Super_retab#Script

```
" Return indent (all whitespace at start of a line), converted from
" tabs to spaces if what = 1, or from spaces to tabs otherwise.
" When converting to tabs, result has no redundant spaces.
function! Indenting(indent, what, cols)
  let spccol = repeat(' ', a:cols)
  let result = substitute(a:indent, spccol, '\t', 'g')
  let result = substitute(result, ' \+\ze\t', '', 'g')
  if a:what == 1
    let result = substitute(result, '\t', spccol, 'g')
  endif
  return result
endfunction

" Convert whitespace used for indenting (before first non-whitespace).
" what = 0 (convert spaces to tabs), or 1 (convert tabs to spaces).
" cols = string with number of columns per tab, or empty to use 'tabstop'.
" The cursor position is restored, but the cursor will be in a different
" column when the number of characters in the indent of the line is changed.
function! IndentConvert(line1, line2, what, cols)
  let savepos = getpos('.')
  let cols = empty(a:cols) ? &tabstop : a:cols
  execute a:line1 . ',' . a:line2 . 's/^\s\+/\=Indenting(submatch(0), a:what, cols)/e'
  call histdel('search', -1)
  call setpos('.', savepos)
endfunction

command! -nargs=? -range=% Space2Tab call IndentConvert(<line1>,<line2>,0,<q-args>)
command! -nargs=? -range=% Tab2Space call IndentConvert(<line1>,<line2>,1,<q-args>)
command! -nargs=? -range=% RetabIndent call IndentConvert(<line1>,<line2>,&et,<q-args>)
```

This helped me a bit more than the answers here did when I first went searching for a solution.

Answer (score 4):

first search for tabs in your file : /^I
:set expandtab
:retab

will work.

Comment: the first part could you please explain that

Answer (score 3):

`expand` is a unix utility to convert tabs to spaces. If you do not want to `set` anything in vim, you can use a shell command from vim:

```
:!% expand -t8
```

Comment: if you just want to expand a portion of the code: first select that portion in visual mode, then press `:`. Now the vim command line shows `:'<,'>`. Then input `!expand -t4` for tab to 4 space. (The resulted command line is like `:'<,'>!expand -t4`)

Answer (score 0):

if u are using makefile or other text file, which need real tab other than some spaces,
add `set noexpandtab` in your ~/vimrc first,
or just input `set noexpandtab` command,
when edit some file with vi(vim)