# How to fix Python indentation

Tags: python

I have some Python code that have inconsistent indentation. There is a lot of mixture of tabs and spaces to make the matter even worse, and even space indentation is not preserved.

The code works as expected, but it's difficult to maintain.

How can I fix the indentation (like [HTML Tidy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Tidy), but for Python) without breaking the code?

---

<sub>Some **editor-specific** advice:</sub>

- <sub>Vi/Vim:</sub>

  - <sub>[Replace tabs with spaces in vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426963)</sub>
  - <sub>[Expand tabs to spaces in vim only in python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986475)</sub>
  - <sub>[Use Vim Retab to solve TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48735671)</sub>
  - <sub>[How to maintain tabs when pasting in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584465)</sub>
- <sub>Notepad++:</sub>

  - <sub>[Convert tabs to spaces in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455037)</sub>
  - <sub>[Auto-indent in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412427)</sub>
  - <sub>[How do I configure Notepad++ to use spaces instead of tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197812/)</sub>
- <sub>Emacs:</sub>

  - <sub>[Indentation not working properly in emacs for python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27032218)</sub>
  - <sub>[Emacs bulk indent for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585091)</sub>
- <sub>Eclipse:</sub>

  - <sub>[indent python file (with pydev) in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654267)</sub>
- <sub>Visual Studio Code:</sub>

  - <sub>[Visual Studio Code indentation for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143985)</sub>

Comment: can you review this link and provide your inputs on how to use reindent.py module--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132481/installing-reindent-python/12132523#comment16227062_12132523

Comment: As mentioned below by @andy-hayden look at this related question - basically `autopep8` provides indentation and much much more:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328406/tool-to-convert-python-code-to-be-pep8-compliant

Comment: This is an insanely useful question, I find myself needing to do this quite often. It's not about "recommending a tool" so much as "how to do it".

Answer (score 303, accepted):

Use the `reindent.py` script that you find in the `Tools/scripts/` directory of your Python installation:

> Change Python (.py) files to use
> 4-space indents and no hard tab
> characters. Also trim excess spaces
> and tabs from ends of lines, and
> remove empty lines at the end of
> files.  Also ensure the last line ends
> with a newline.

Have a look at that script for detailed usage instructions.

---

NOTE: If your linux distro does not have reindent installed by default with Python:

Many linux distros do not have `reindent` installed by default with `python` --> one easy way to get `reindent` is to do `pip install reindent`.

p.s. An alternative to `pip` is to use your distros package manager (i.e. `apt-get`, `yum`, `dnf`) but then you need to figure out what package has the command line tool because each distro has the tool in a different package.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not part of the normal Python install on Debian and Ubuntu; it's split out into the `python-examples` package.

Comment: Excellent! So all that Debian and Ubuntu users need do is to apt-get that package. Alternatively, the script is also at http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Tools/scripts/reindent.py?revision=66903&view=markup .

Comment: Works like a charm, I left the question open for a while so you can enjoy more up votes.
BTW, is there a way to force constant indention per file? I want python to allow only 4 spaces per indentation level and fail the parsing otherwise. If the answer is yes then I will open a new question.

Comment: @Shay Erlichmen: Try "python -tt yourscript.py"

Comment: @nosklo's right, -tt gives errors on inconsistent tab usage (however it does tolerate _consistent_ tab usage, 3-space indent vs 4, etc, so it's still more permissive than @Shay would want).

Comment: Fedora/RedHat/CentOS users should install the "python-tools" package.

Comment: Just to add to ephemient's comment: once `python-examples` is installed, you'll find reindent in `/usr/share/doc/pythonX.X/examples/Tools/scripts/reindent.py`.

Comment: but what if i want tabs? (why? because it’s The Right Way™). seriously: this script is no good if it isn’t even flexible enough to do this.

Comment: Following up to @LarryHastings, currently after installing `python-examples` the script is at `/usr/share/doc/libpythonX.Y/examples/Tools/scripts/reindent.py` (note that `pythonX.Y` became `libpythonX.Y`).

Comment: how to use this script on Windows ?

Comment: @mounaim, find where `reindent.py` lives on your Windows installation and run it with your installation of Python just like you'd run any other Python script.  If you can't find it see http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Tools/scripts/reindent.py (for a Python 2 version) or https://github.com/certik/python-3.2/blob/master/Tools/scripts/reindent.py (for a Python 3 version).  The start of each script gives copious instructions.

Comment: On my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian, after having installed python3.2-examples by apt-get, I found the reindent.py script in /usr/share/doc/libpython3.2/examples/scripts/reindent.py. (No Tools directory.)

Comment: On Mac with brew, I used `find /usr | grep reindent` and found `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/share/doc/python3.5/examples/Tools/scripts/reindent.py elevator_test.py`

Comment: Is there a problem with `windows 64 bit` `pip` and `powershell`? It is not working in that scenario.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583682/reindent-py-not-working-in-windows7

Comment: I don't know why 200+ votes on this, just tried it and it didn't work on tab/spaced mixed file (win 7  python 3.4

Comment: Following @Dorian instructions, use `find /usr | grep reindent` and in **Arch Linux** 2019 find at `/usr/lib/python3.8/Tools/scripts/reindent.py`.

Comment: still works like a charm in **2022** - works for multiple **tabs**, even if I have a function with indentation level of 3 tabs or 4 tabs or many more or tabs/spaces mixed (as long as the indentation rule is followed in the function as a rule - can be different for different functions) , it works perfectly - why use something else, when there is something that is already shipped in the python release itself.

Comment: **`python-examples` is not available** for Debian 12 in any APT sources.

Answer (score 70):

I would reach for [autopep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8) to do this:

```sh
$ # see what changes it would make
$ autopep8 path/to/file.py --select=E101,E121 --diff

$ # make these changes
$ autopep8 path/to/file.py --select=E101,E121 --in-place
```

*Note: [E101 and E121](https://github.com/hhatto/autopep8#features) are pep8 indentation (I think you can simply pass `--select=E1` to fix all indentation related issues - those starting with E1).*

You can apply this to your entire project using recursive flag:

```sh
$ autopep8 package_dir --recursive --select=E101,E121 --in-place
```

*See also [Tool to convert Python code to be PEP8 compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14328499/1240268).*

Comment: this is awesome... I've been looking for a tool like ruby's rubocop for python

Comment: `autopep8` fails if the syntax is incorrect. you can confirm that using `python -tt <file.py>`

Comment: doesnt work, left mix of tabs and spaces for me

Answer (score 61):

If you're using [Vim](http://www.vim.org/), see [`:h retab`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:retab).

```
                                                        *:ret* *:retab*
:[range]ret[ab][!] [new_tabstop]
                        Replace all sequences of white-space containing a
                        <Tab> with new strings of white-space using the new
                        tabstop value given.  If you do not specify a new
                        tabstop size or it is zero, Vim uses the current value
                        of 'tabstop'.
                        The current value of 'tabstop' is always used to
                        compute the width of existing tabs.
                        With !, Vim also replaces strings of only normal
                        spaces with tabs where appropriate.
                        With 'expandtab' on, Vim replaces all tabs with the
                        appropriate number of spaces.
                        This command sets 'tabstop' to the new value given,
                        and if performed on the whole file, which is default,
                        should not make any visible change.
                        Careful: This command modifies any <Tab> characters
                        inside of strings in a C program.  Use "\t" to avoid
                        this (that's a good habit anyway).
                        ":retab!" may also change a sequence of spaces by
                        <Tab> characters, which can mess up a printf().
                        {not in Vi}
                        Not available when |+ex_extra| feature was disabled at
                        compile time.
```

For example, if you simply type

```
:ret
```

all your tabs will be expanded into spaces.

You may want to

```
:se et  " shorthand for :set expandtab
```

to make sure that any new lines will not use literal tabs.

---

If you're not using Vim,

```
perl -i.bak -pe "s/\t/' 'x(8-pos()%8)/eg" file.py
```

will replace tabs with spaces, assuming tab stops every 8 characters, in `file.py` (with the original going to `file.py.bak`, just in case).  Replace the 8s with 4s if your tab stops are every 4 spaces instead.

Answer (score 61):

### `autopep8 -i script.py`

Use [autopep8](https://pypi.org/project/autopep8/)

`autopep8` *automagically* formats Python code to conform to the [`PEP 8`
`nullstyle`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guide. It uses the `pep8` utility to determine what parts of the
`nullcode` needs to be formatted. `autopep8` is capable of fixing most of the
`nullformatting` issues that can be reported by `pep8`.

```
pip install autopep8
autopep8 script.py    # print only
autopep8 -i script.py # write file
```

Comment: i have just one line code with "import os" and 4 spaces before it  but its not indenting that one ....any reason why

Comment: @pkm 4 spaces (or any indention that is a multiple of 4) is part of the PEP8

Comment: doesnt work on mine. just leaves tabs and spaces as is

Answer (score 18):

Using Vim, it shouldn't be more involved than hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and then typing...

```
:%s/\t/    /g
```

...on the file you want to change. That will convert all tabs to four spaces. If you have inconsistent spacing as well, then that will be more difficult.

Comment: can you track down the original coder(s) and apply enhanced interrogation techniques?  There is nothing worse than inconsistently indented code.

Comment: @Ben The inconsistent indention is the least of our problems from that guy :)

Comment: What happens if tabs are in other places, such as in a string literal?

Answer (score 11):

There is also [PythonTidy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PythonTidy/1.16) (since you said you like HTML Tidy).

It can do a lot more than just clean up tabs though. If you like that type of thing, it's worth a look.

Answer (score 8):

On most UNIX-like systems, you can also run:

```
expand -t4 oldfilename.py > newfilename.py
```

from the command line, changing the number if you want to replace tabs with a number of spaces other than 4. You can easily write a shell script to do this with a bunch of files at once, retaining the original file names.

Comment: Note that using the same file doesn't work and leaves you with an empty file, but this answer actually works and I use it when I need to convert my tabs to spaces. Could anyone explain the downvote? I'll up it +1.

Comment: Is there any possible way to recover the overwritten file? Just used the above method and my day's worth of code vanished *facepalm*. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The reindent script did not work for me, due to some missing module. Anyway, I found this `sed` command which does the job perfect for me:

```
sed -r 's/^([  ]*)([^ ])/\1\1\2/' file.py
```

Comment: Illegal options -r.

Answer (score 5):

If you're lazy (like me), you can also download a trial version of Wingware Python IDE, which has an auto-fix tool for messed up indentation. It works pretty well.
http://www.wingware.com/

Answer (score 3):

Try Emacs. It has good support for indentation needed in Python. Please check this link http://python.about.com/b/2007/09/24/emacs-tips-for-python-programmers.htm

Comment: python-mode is nice for writing Python, but nothing at the link describes how to *fix* indentation in an existing file.

Comment: M-x untabify will turn tabs into space in emacs

Comment: The link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to a page with the title *"C Programming Language for Beginners "* (!).

Answer (score 2):

Try [IDLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE_%28Python%29), and use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to find indentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution for this problem. You can first type ":retab" and then ":retab!", then everything would be fine

Comment: Type "`:retab`" in what context. In [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29)?

Answer (score 0):

In case of trying to find tool to make your `2-space indented` python script to a `tab indented` version, just use this online tool:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_python_formatter.htm

Answer (score 0):

There is also a Google awesome project called [YAPF](https://github.com/google/yapf)

It can automatically reformat the whole project or check if the project has correct indentation/format. I used that in a commercial project and I recommend that.