# python help needed

Tags: python, indentation

```
import os
import sys, urllib2, urllib
import re
import time
from threading import Thread

class testit(Thread):
   def __init__ (self):
      Thread.__init__(self)
   def run(self):
        url = 'http://games.espnstar.asia/the-greatest-odi/post_brackets.php'
        data = urllib.urlencode([('id',"btn_13_9_13"),  ('matchNo',"13")])
        req = urllib2.Request(url)
        fd = urllib2.urlopen(req, data)
<TAB>fd.close()
<TAB>"""while 1:
                data = fd.read(1024)
                if not len(data):
                        break
                sys.stdout.write(data)"""
        url2 = 'http://games.espnstar.asia/the-greatest-odi/post_perc.php'
        data2 = urllib.urlencode([('id',"btn_13_9_13"),  ('matchNo',"13")])
        req2 = urllib2.Request(url2)
        fd2 = urllib2.urlopen(req2, data2)
<TAB>#prints current votes
        while 1:
                data2 = fd2.read(1024)
                if not len(data2):
                        break
                sys.stdout.write(data2)
<TAB>fd2.close()
        print time.ctime()
        print " ending thread\n"

i=-1
while i<0:
   current = testit()
   time.sleep(0.001) #decrease this like 0.0001 for more loops
   current.start()
```

Hey can anybody help me finding out the error in the code
Its saying inconsistent use of tabs an spaces in indentation

Comment: Don't be a dick. This guy is a n00b, and tabs vs spaces is a legitimately confusing issue. They look exactly the same!

Comment: @joeforker: (1) I'm trying to help him solve his problem.  (2) Read the OP's comments on @Thomas Owens answer.  (3) N00b or not, the question has already been asked on SO regarding Python. (4) It's covered in the Python tutorial.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024435/howto-fix-python-indentation

Comment: Sure, 'please edit it for me' is pretty extreme. A pointer to the duplicate question is useful, but he probably doesn't know what \t means yet.

Answer (score 5):

I edited your post to replace all the tabs with `<TAB>`. You need to delete the indentation on those lines and line it back up with spaces. Some editors can do that for you, but I don't know which editor you are using.

If you get serious about Python, you should reconfigure your editor to always insert 4 spaces when the tab key is pressed. You can also try changing the amount of indentation provided by the tab character or in some editors print a visible symbol for the tab character so you can see where the problem is.

Comment: You're a kind soul.  Now could you help the OP with vaccumming his office on Tuesday nights ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it looks like the code formatter here on Stack Overflow turns everything into spaces. But the error is quite self-explanatory. Python, unlike the curly-brace languages (like C, C++, and Java) uses indentation to mark blocks of code. The error means that a block is improperly indented.

Comment: hey catually i m a novice in python.
can u edit the above code and provide the correct one. please

Comment: You're seriously asking someone to fix tabs and spaces for you?

Comment: you just have to indent stuff properly, and only using spaces (not tabs). You can do it by yourself.