# Emacs bulk indent for Python

Tags: python, emacs, ssh

Working with Python in Emacs if I want to add a try/except to a block of code, I often find that I am having to indent the whole block, line by line.  In Emacs, how do you indent the whole block at once.

I am not an experienced Emacs user, but just find it is the best tool for working through ssh.  I am using Emacs on the command line(Ubuntu), not as a gui, if that makes any difference.

Comment: `C-c >` for right.
`C-c <` for left

Answer (score 240, accepted):

If you are programming Python using Emacs, then you should probably be using python-mode. With python-mode, after marking the block of code,

`C-c >` or `C-c C-l`  shifts the region 4 spaces to the right

`C-c <` or `C-c C-r`  shifts the region 4 spaces to the left

If you need to shift code by two levels of indention, or some arbitary amount you can prefix the command with an argument:

`C-u 8 C-c >`     shifts the region 8 spaces to the right

`C-u 8 C-c <`     shifts the region 8 spaces to the left

Another alternative is to use `M-x indent-rigidly` which is bound to `C-x TAB`:

`C-u 8 C-x TAB`   shifts the region 8 spaces to the right

`C-u -8 C-x TAB`  shifts the region 8 spaces to the left

Also useful are the [rectangle commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangles.html) that operate on rectangles of text instead of lines of text.

For example, after marking a rectangular region,

`C-x r o` inserts blank space to fill the rectangular region (effectively shifting code to the right)

`C-x r k` kills  the rectangular region (effectively shifting code to the left)

`C-x r t` prompts for a string to replace the rectangle with.  Entering `C-u 8 <space>` will then enter 8 spaces.

PS. With Ubuntu, to make python-mode the default mode for all .py files, simply install the `python-mode` package.

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly.  with Emacs22 isn't python-mode automatically enabled with all .py files?  Anyway, the C-c > works just fine.

Comment: @Vernon: `C-c >` is defined in python-mode.el, so I think you must have installed the `python-mode` package somewhere along the way. Glad it works for you.

Comment: C-c > works fine in Emacs 23.2 without installing python-mode as it works with the provided python.el

Comment: @landstatic: Thanks for the information. That makes me think perhaps all the commands listed above work the same for python-mode.el or python.el?

Comment: Just to add that the C-c > and C-c > are also bind to C-c C-l and C-C-c C-r (left and right). IMHO these are much easier to type. Please, could you update the answer the reflect this? (thanks)

Comment: @redobot: `C-c C-l` and `C-c C-r` must be custom bindings you've set up yourself. If you run `emacs -q` (to run emacs without loading an init file) you'll see there is no binding for `C-c C-l` or `C-c C-r` in Python mode.

Comment: No, probably hey are only available in the latest version of the mode. If you take a look to the file https://github.com/emacsmirror/python-mode/blob/master/python-mode.el you can find them (just look for py-shift-left and py-shift-right)

Comment: As an aside, emacs is my editor of choice for python code purely because of python-mode. I've *never* encountered a indent syntax error using it.

Comment: Can I do `C-c <` and `<`  followed by `<` to continue indention? @unutbu

Answer (score 11):

In addition to `indent-region`, which is mapped to `C-M-\` by default, the rectangle edit commands are very useful for Python.  Mark a region as normal, then:

- `C-x r t` (`string-rectangle`): will prompt you for characters you'd like to insert into each line; great for inserting a certain number of spaces
- `C-x r k` (`kill-rectangle`): remove a rectangle region; great for removing indentation

You can also `C-x r y` (`yank-rectangle`), but that's only rarely useful.

Answer (score 4):

`indent-region` mapped to `C-M-\` should do the trick.

Comment: This is terrible advice.  Python indentation cannot be inferred (since it is syntax!) so ident-region is useless.

Answer (score 4):

Do indentation interactively.

1. Select the region to be indented.
2. C-x <kbd>TAB</kbd>.
3. Use arrows (<kbd><-</kbd> and <kbd>-></kbd>) to indent interactively.
4. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> three times when you are done with the required indentation.

Copied from my post in: [Indent several lines in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713743/indent-several-lines-in-emacs/56024097#56024097)

Answer (score 2):

I've been using this function to handle my indenting and unindenting:

```
(defun unindent-dwim (&optional count-arg)
  "Keeps relative spacing in the region.  Unindents to the next multiple of the current tab-width"
  (interactive)
  (let ((deactivate-mark nil)
        (beg (or (and mark-active (region-beginning)) (line-beginning-position)))
        (end (or (and mark-active (region-end)) (line-end-position)))
        (min-indentation)
        (count (or count-arg 1)))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char beg)
      (while (< (point) end)
        (add-to-list 'min-indentation (current-indentation))
        (forward-line)))
    (if (< 0 count)
        (if (not (< 0 (apply 'min min-indentation)))
            (error "Can't indent any more.  Try `indent-rigidly` with a negative arg.")))
    (if (> 0 count)
        (indent-rigidly beg end (* (- 0 tab-width) count))
      (let (
            (indent-amount
             (apply 'min (mapcar (lambda (x) (- 0 (mod x tab-width))) min-indentation))))
        (indent-rigidly beg end (or
                                 (and (< indent-amount 0) indent-amount)
                                 (* (or count 1) (- 0 tab-width))))))))
```

And then I assign it to a keyboard shortcut:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s-[") 'unindent-dwim)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-]") (lambda () (interactive) (unindent-dwim -1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm an Emacs newb, so this answer it probably bordering on useless.

None of the answers mentioned so far cover re-indentation of literals like `dict` or `list`. E.g. `M-x indent-region` or `M-x python-indent-shift-right` and company aren't going to help if you've cut-and-pasted the following literal and need it to be re-indented sensibly:

```
    foo = {
  'bar' : [
     1,
    2,
        3 ],
      'baz' : {
     'asdf' : {
        'banana' : 1,
        'apple' : 2 } } }
```

It feels like `M-x indent-region` should do something sensibly in `python-mode`, but that's not (yet) the case.

For the specific case where your literals are bracketed, using TAB on the lines in question gets what you want (because whitespace doesn't play a role).

So what I've been doing in such cases is quickly recording a [keyboard macro](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros#keyboard_macro) like `<f3> C-n TAB <f4>` as in F3, Ctrl-n (or down arrow), TAB, F4, and then using F4 repeatedly to apply the macro can save a couple of keystrokes. Or you can do `C-u 10 C-x e` to apply it 10 times.

(I know it doesn't sound like much, but try re-indenting 100 lines of garbage literal without missing down-arrow, and then having to go up 5 lines and repeat things ;) ).

Answer (score 2):

I use the following snippet. On tab when the selection is inactive, it indents the current line (as it normally does); when the selection is inactive, it indents the whole region to the right.

```
(defun my-python-tab-command (&optional _)
  "If the region is active, shift to the right; otherwise, indent current line."
  (interactive)
  (if (not (region-active-p))
      (indent-for-tab-command)
    (let ((lo (min (region-beginning) (region-end)))
          (hi (max (region-beginning) (region-end))))
      (goto-char lo)
      (beginning-of-line)
      (set-mark (point))
      (goto-char hi)
      (end-of-line)
      (python-indent-shift-right (mark) (point)))))
(define-key python-mode-map [remap indent-for-tab-command] 'my-python-tab-command)
```

Answer (score -4):

I do something like this universally

```
;; intent whole buffer 
(defun iwb ()
  "indent whole buffer"
  (interactive)
  ;;(delete-trailing-whitespace)
  (indent-region (point-min) (point-max) nil)
  (untabify (point-min) (point-max)))
```

Comment: Since whitespace is part of the syntax in Python, indent-region on the whole file is a bad idea.