# Indent several lines in Emacs

Tags: emacs, indentation

In my Emacs, `space` key can indent correctly 1 line. If I select several lines, and press `space` key, the indenting does not work.

By following this [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Multi_002dline-Indent.html), I try `C-M-\` or `C-M-q`, but `C-M` deletes directly the whole block selected.

Here is my [`.emacs`](http://pastebin.com/ATYEiXGF), could anyone help?

Comment: [Indenting Several Lines](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Multi_002dline-Indent.html).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you want Emacs to correctly indent multiple lines, then the command is `C-META \` also known as `C-M-\`. In other words, it's not `Control - M`, but `Control - Meta - Backslash` (<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd> on most keyboards)

Comment: In particular, this issues the `indent-region` command.  It does nothing without the `column` parameter.  To provide this, one must use the universal argument prefix `C-u` followed by the column number to indent to.  For example, if you wish to indent to the third column, then the key sequence is `C-u 3 C-M-\ `.  For me, while this does indent the region, it also destroys the current indentation scheme.  It forces each line the region to the same indentation level.

Answer (score 128):

Select multiply lines, then type <kbd>C-u 8 C-x Tab</kbd>, it will indent the region by `8` spaces.

<kbd>C-u -4 C-x Tab</kbd> will un-indent by `4` spaces

Comment: This is the **only** one that's worked for me, and can't be found it [GNU Emacs Indent Multiple Lines](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Multi_002dline-Indent.html).  Terrific contribution

Comment: AND it even works when your in Evil-mode! major super ultra win!

Comment: It is also the only one that worked for me. unknown why  C-M-\ doesn't work.

Comment: warning "it will ident that region by 8 spaces"  no by one tab, and tab isn't 8 spaces, however it may be represented instead of 8 spaces!

Comment: On emacs in OSC C-M\ does not work. How do you select the block of code anyway (without the use of mouse)

Comment: Very short and easy command :) works for me in MacOS `C-h C-a C-u 8 C-x Tab`

Comment: It is described at [GNU Emacs Indentation Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Indentation-Commands.html) (which is linked from the mentioned `Indent Multiple Lines` article). In `Emacs` I found it by `C-h i m <Emacs> <RET> i <indent>`

Answer (score 30):

*[Warning: This approach might lead to errors as mentioned in one of the comments. Iniviting suggestions to fix it.]*

Steps to do indentation interactively.

1. Select the region to be indented.
2. C-x <kbd>TAB</kbd>.
3. Use arrows (← and →) to indent interactively.
4. Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> three times when you are done with the required indentation.

Comment: This will have unintended results if [CUA](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CuaMode) mode is used

Comment: Do you mean that tabs and spaces will get messed up?

Comment: C-x TAB calls "indent-rigidly" function in my buffers, so if C-x TAB doesn't work you can call M-x: indent-rigidly. And instead of Esc, down arrow may end it too.

Comment: C-x is text cut in CUA mode; indent-rigidly would need to be remapped to another key combination, a la @nephewtom's answer here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/31564/emacs-bulk-indent-for-python-while-cua-mode-is-enabled

Answer (score 4):

None of the above method worked for me except Kev's- and that is too verbose for my slow fingers.

For me, I can highlight the region and press <kbd>Alt-left arrow</kbd> . Strangely, even though <kbd>Alt</kbd> registers as meta in emacs, <kbd>Esc-left arrow</kbd>  doesn't work.

Comment: This always works for me on whatever emacs I use. I've tried it on many different emacs installs on various os's. Much quicker than all those multiple keystroke commands, too.

Comment: The "C-u 4 C-x Tab" solution worked for me but the one you just provided is the best I found for quick reorganisation of my code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another method to indent several lines is just to use the commands to edit several lines: [Edit multiple lines at once in Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761706/edit-multiple-lines-at-once-in-emacs).

Basically, select region and then `C-x r t`+`Tab`.