# Changing Python indentation amount in Emacs

Tags: python, emacs

Because I have

```
(setq python-indent-offset 4)
```

in my .emacs, when I start with code such as

```
def fn():
  foo = bar()
  if bar1 == bar2:
    if blah1 == blah2:
      return yay
```

and mark-whole-buffer (C-x h) followed by indent-region (C-M-\ ), I am expecting to get:

```
def fn():
    foo = bar()
    if bar1 == bar2:
        if blah1 == blah2:
            return yay
```

but I get instead:

```
def fn():
    foo = bar()
  if bar1 == bar2:
    if blah1 == blah2:
      return yay
```

Yet indent-region works just fine with curly-brace delimited languages. Is there a way to get it to work with an indentation-based language such as Python?

*Please note:*

1. I am [aware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13807070/704972) of [Reindent](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Reindent/0.1.0) but I'd like to stay within Emacs.
2. I am well acquainted with [string-rectangle (C-x r t) and python-indent-shift-right/left (C-c >)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2585406/704972), but neither these nor their variants do what I'm asking.

Comment: The issue seems to be that in `python-indent-region`, there is a check to see if the line is on a block start. If it is on a block start (such as if in an if statement) it will skip the line and not change the indentation. You should raise it as a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively you can call the python package from within emacs and have it replace the buffer.

```
(defun my-py-reindent ()
         "Reindent the current file with pypi's reindent."
         (interactive)
           (shell-command-to-string (format "reindent %s" (buffer-file-name)))
           (revert-buffer t t t))
```

Pretty easy ! (doc used: http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Emacs_Lisp_Cheat_Sheet#File)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is a perfect solution and as such I would not want to push this as a patch to emacs-devel but since the issue is in `python-indent-region` (I left a note about this as a comment). We can try to redefine that function as such:

```
(defun python-indent-region (start end)
  "Indent a Python region automagically.

Called from a program, START and END specify the region to indent."
  (let ((deactivate-mark nil))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char end)
      (setq end (point-marker))
      (goto-char start)
      (or (bolp) (forward-line 1))
      (while (< (point) end)
        (or (and (bolp) (eolp))
            (when (and
                   ;; Skip if previous line is empty or a comment.
                   (save-excursion
                     (let ((line-is-comment-p
                            (python-info-current-line-comment-p)))
                       (forward-line -1)
                       (not
                        (or (and (python-info-current-line-comment-p)
                                 ;; Unless this line is a comment too.
                                 (not line-is-comment-p))
                            (python-info-current-line-empty-p)))))
                   ;; Don't mess with strings, unless it's the
                   ;; enclosing set of quotes or a docstring.
                   (or (not (python-syntax-context 'string))
                       (eq
                        (syntax-after
                         (+ (1- (point))
                            (current-indentation)
                            (python-syntax-count-quotes (char-after) (point))))
                        (string-to-syntax "|"))
                       (python-info-docstring-p)))
              (python-indent-line)))
        (forward-line 1))
      (move-marker end nil))))
```

The part that I changed was simply removing the check to see if the line was a block ender, denter, or block-start and running `(python-indent-line)` in all of those cases.

I've tested this on this example and some others and they seem to work. If it doesn't work I'd love to know!

Comment: Hmm.. After eval-region, restarting Emacs, and using another (bleeding edge) version of Emacs, the function name python-indent-region is not recognized after M-x. Investigating. I've also tried to change that name.

Comment: It shouldn't be visible through m-x, it should be called by C-M-\ though when you use that command