# How do I configure Notepad++ to use spaces instead of tabs?

Tags: notepad++

Notepad++ keeps inserting tabs which later messes up my code. This doesn't just happen when I hit the tab key, but other times as well. I want it to use 4 spaces instead of tabs.

How can I make Notepad++ insert spaces instead of tabs?

Comment: The linked question is not a dupe. This is not asking about how to run a macro that converts, it's asking about never entering tabs in the first place when indenting your code for you. And the answer  here is correct

Comment: This question should be closed as it is off topic. This question belongs on Super User

Comment: @MikeCaron That is incorrect See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61726/are-questions-about-ides-on-topic

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197812/how-does-one-configure-notepad-to-use-spaces-instead-of-tabs.

Comment: And for Python, this makes the difference between correct code and not. IMHO, Notepad++ should be shipping with this setting turned on by default for Python code.

Comment: @Omnifarious: v7.8.6 (April 2020) has the `python` option set to use spaces. Not sure how long this has been there. As a side note...Notepad++ is awesome.

Comment: @AlainD to add on to your comment.  I had opened Settings -> Preferences -> Language.  My `[Default]` "language" on the right hand side under `Tab Settings` was set to use Tabs, but my `python` scripts were still having tabs being replaced by 4 spaces.

scrolling down through the right hand side list (`Tab Settings`), I found an entry for `python`.  Lo and behold, it was the _only_ language set to `Replace By Space`.  No idea why, I've never had this set.  But toggling the box to off/unchecked fixed my issue where I was getting 4 spaces per `tab` instead of getting a tab `character`.  Thx!

Answer (score 719, accepted):

Go to the *Preferences* menu command under menu *Settings*, and select *Language Menu/Tab Settings*, depending on your version. Earlier versions use Tab Settings. Later versions use Language. Click the *Replace with space* check box. Set the size to 4.

[image: Screenshot]

See documentation: https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/preferences/#language

Comment: Ah Language, now that makes sense.

Comment: The Notepad++ documentation is way outdated. The link above points to Tuxfamily, and they started releasing new builds on Tuxfamily back in [2010](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-5.7-release-(outside-the-usa).html). The online documentation site on Tuxfamily was published in [2011](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/release-5.8.7-and-online-documentation-site.html) and it's for version 5.8.7. Notepad++ is at version 6.5.5 right now, and the "Help Contents" menu option brings up a local copy of the doc site. Visiting [Tuxfamily](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/) site returns a 404.

Comment: It's unfortunate that the doc site is so outdated. But the screenshot above points correctly to the appropriate option (version 6.5.5). So this setting is located under "tab settings" now, it's no longer shared with "language menu".

Comment: The setting is now under **Language**, instead of **Tab Settings**.

Comment: Well, now the Notepad++ actually always inserts tabs as spaces, even when the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: You may want to set the preference per language. For example, say you wish to use spaces in C/C++ code (`*.cpp` and `*.h`), but tabs in normal text files (`*.txt`). Set `[Default]` with `Replace by space` unticked to use tabs generally. Now select `cpp`, untick `Use default value` and tick `Replace by space`. Repeat for all the other source code file types you use.

Answer (score 67):

In my Notepad++ `7.2.2`, the `Preferences` section it's a bit different.

The option is located at: `Settings` / `Preferences` / `Language` / `Replace by space` as in the Screenshot.

[image: Screenshot of the windows with preferences]

Comment: This is the new settings for latest Notepad++

Answer (score 4):

I have NotePad++ v6.8.3, and it was in Settings → Preferences → Tab Settings → `[Default]` → Replace by space:

[image: NotePad++ Preferences]

[image: NotePad++ Tab Settings]