# Unexpected indent

Tags: python, indentation

I'm getting `IndentationError: unexpected indent` even though I wrote the code exactly as shown in the book (*[Learn Pythhon the hard way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex25.html)*)

I'm sure that I'm using exactly four spaces to indent the lines which come after "def".

I am using Python 2.7 on Windows 7.

Here's the error I get in [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell):

```
PS C:\Users\Kiedis\python> python ex25.py
  File "ex25.py", line 3
    return sorted(words)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

And here are the first three lines of my code:

```
def sort_words(words):
    """Sorts the words"""
    return sorted(words)
```

Comment: I'm using Notepadd++ to compile my code, if that matters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing tabs and spaces *anyway*; run your script with:

```
python -tt ex25.py
```

to detect where the error lies.

Then configure your editor to *only* use spaces for indentation, and re-indent your file. See [How does one configure Notepad++ to use spaces instead of tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197812/how-do-i-configure-notepad-to-use-spaces-instead-of-tabs)

Comment: thank you Martijn. I configured Notepad++ to replace Tab by Space. I'm still getting the same error but i suppose i need to restart Notepad++ and rewrite the whole code manually?

Comment: You can have Notepad++ fix your indentation for you: [Notepad++ tabs to spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/q/455037). Did you run `python -tt` on your script?

Comment: yes, I ran python -tt ex25.py and got the following:

PS C:\Users\Kiedis\python> python -tt ex25.py
  File "ex25.py", line 7
    word = words.pop(0)
                      ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: @ThomasH.: Then line 7 has mixed tabs and spaces. Run the `Leading tabs to spaces` TextFX on your file, and see if you need to adjust indentations and safe your file. Then run your code again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the comment ("""Sorts the words""") is not directly bellow the def sort_words(words). This raises an error. Did this solve your problem?

Comment: no, it's not directly below def... The first double-quote is 4 spaces from the left. And "return" is 4 spaces from the left

Comment: Did you make sure you gave arguments when calling the function?
Like sort_words("Words")
You already said you used spaces instead of tabs so that can't be the problem.