# Notepad++: print a tab character with 'Replace by Space' enabled

Tags: notepad++

This question explains how to configure Notepad++ to use spaces instead of tab: 
[How does one configure Notepad++ to use spaces instead of tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197812/how-does-one-configure-notepad-to-use-spaces-instead-of-tabs)

With this setting enabled, is there a hotkey that will allow you to override this and print a tab character?

I want to keep the setting enabled, but still have a way to print a tab key easily without changing the setting back (for those odd times when you really do need a tab).

Answer (score 1):

I think an uncomplicated way is simply to press the combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>

But you can not continue with the Tab key on the same line.

[image]

A PDF print example from the lines above looks like:

[image]