# Biopython Indentation Error

Tags: indentation, biopython

I've been dabbling in biopython for about a year and I recently upgraded to Biopython release 1.59. I've been refreshing my skills with some tutorials but I always get the error below when I run a for loop and any module from the biopython library:

```
    IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I only get this error when I call the .py file written in Komodo Edit version 7.0.2 from the command line terminal:

```
    Priyas-iMac:~ Priya$ python /Users/priya/Documents/Python/Tutorials/BioParse.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/priya/Documents/Python/Tutorials/BioParse.py", line 4, in <module>
        SeqIO.write(rc, "/Users/priya/Documents/Python/Tutorials/ls_orchid_rc.fasta", "fasta")
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/__init__.py", line 400, in write
        from Bio import AlignIO
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/AlignIO/__init__.py", line 147, in <module>
        import NexusIO
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/AlignIO/NexusIO.py", line 19, in <module>
        from Bio.Nexus import Nexus
      File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/Nexus/Nexus.py", line 15, in <module>
        import os,sys, math, random, copy
      File "/Users/Priya/Documents/Python/Tutorials/random.py", line 27
        randLowHigh(5,10)
        ^
    IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

When I use the command line to call old .py files that I wrote a year ago as above they run fine. And when I start up python directly and type in the tutorial example line by line it works fine:

```
    Priyas-iMac:~ Priya$ python 
    Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 19 2012, 00:55:09) 
    [GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> from Bio import SeqIO
    >>> for seq_record in SeqIO.parse("/Users/priya/Documents/Python/Tutorials/ls_orchid.txt","fasta"):
    ...      print seq_record.id
    ... 
    gi|2765658|emb|Z78533.1|CIZ78533
    gi|2765657|emb|Z78532.1|CCZ78532
```

How can I fix my .py file so I can just run it from the terminal?

Any insight into this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Priya

Comment: Could you post the .py file? Probably, you forgot to indent line 27.

Comment: I'm not sure how to post a file directly, could you tell me how?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that when I was originally learning python, I stupidly named a tutorial file "random.py" to practice making a random number generator. When biopython was importing other required modules, it kept pointing to that file instead of the random library module:

```
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/Nexus/Nexus.py", line 15, in <module>
    import os,sys, math, random, copy
  File "/Users/Priya/Documents/Python/Tutorials/random.py", line 27
    randLowHigh(5,10)
```

Thanks for the help, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Check if all the files and modules imported have the same indentation (tabs or spaces and same number of spaces).

From the [Style guide for Python code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) you can read:

> Use 4 spaces per indentation level.
>
> For really old code that you don't want to mess up, you can continue to use 8-space tabs.

And regarding tabs and spaces:

> Never mix tabs and spaces.
>
> The most popular way of indenting Python is with spaces only. The
> second-most popular way is with tabs only. Code indented with a
> mixture of tabs and spaces should be converted to using spaces
> exclusively. When invoking the Python command line interpreter with
> the -t option, it issues warnings about code that illegally mixes tabs
> and spaces. When using -tt these warnings become errors. These options
> are highly recommended!
>
> For new projects, spaces-only are strongly recommended over tabs. Most
> editors have features that make this easy to do.

Maybe Komodo is changing something automatically (some editors do). Try to edit the file in a more plain editor and look for the tabs. You may have an option to show you the spaces and tabs as visible.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried replacing the tab with four spaces in Komodo Edit and it gives me the same error. I also tried typing it into Text Editor (on a Mac) fresh and get the same error. I will try and read some more about this today and see if Komodo Edit is doing something weird. Thanks again!

Comment: Have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024435/howto-fix-python-indentation