# Installing reindent python

Tags: python

I have lot of issues with Python indentation with the Notepad++. Inorder to resolve, I tried to install Python reindent module but Im unsuccessful on how to use it.
If anyone had been successful, please let me know..

Here are the steps I tried.

1.Using easy install I tried to install  the package,

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>easy_install reindent
Searching for reindent
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/reindent/
Best match: Reindent 0.1.1
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/R/Reindent/Reindent-0.1.1.tar
.gz#md5=878352c36c421a0b944607efba3b01ad
Processing Reindent-0.1.1.tar.gz
Running Reindent-0.1.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\premvi~1\appdat
a\local\temp\easy_install-qdahih\Reindent-0.1.1\egg-dist-tmp-1z1zw8
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Adding reindent 0.1.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installing reindent script to C:\Python27\Scripts

Installed c:\python27\lib\site-packages\reindent-0.1.1-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for reindent
Finished processing dependencies for reindent
```

1. when I did a import command on the python GUI it was successful.
2. I get the below error when I try to use it.

```
>>> import reindent
>>> reindent -d c:/python27/wxpython/ch2-updateui.py
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> reindent -d c:\python2\wxpython\ch2-updateui.py
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Please let me know how to resolve it.

Comment: You're probably mixing tabs and spaces. I don't know Notepad++, but there may be some option to be able to use the "tab" key to insert 4 spaces instead of tabs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to run the command from the Python interpreter instead of the command line. As reindent is a script program, it needs to be run from the command line.

You want to use either

```
 C:\...\> python -m reindent -d C:\Python27\wxpython\ch2-updateui.py
```

or just

```
 C:\...\> reindent -d C:\Python27\wxpython\ch2-updateui.py
```

at your command prompt.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about the package, but the command you are using indeed does not conform to Python syntax. I'd guess you need to run it in your terminal, not Python interpreter.

Comment: @user1050619 You have installed it all right, but you are using it wrong. When you import it, it works, but `reindent -d c:/python27/wxpython/ch2-updateui.py` is by no means a valid Python command. My guess is that it should be run from terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading [this as reindent.bat](https://gist.github.com/1455509) in your C:\Python27\Scripts. Then it should just be a matter of `reindent path\to\file.py`