# reindent.py usage for newbie

Tags: python, python-2.7, indentation

I am trying to remove and correct the file with reindent module in python 2.7 on windows machine. from windows command line when I try to use the following solution it gives me and error.
[Installing reindent python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132481/installing-reindent-python#12132727)

> **Erros is;** "**reindent is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file**." when i checked to install
>   with **pip install reindent**, it says;
>   **Requirement already satisfied: reindent in c:\python27\lib\site-packages**.

indentation has been the a big issue for a newbie like me in my journey to learning python.

Comment: Is the path for your Python 2.7 installation set in your environment variables?

Comment: I dont understand why indentation makes learning so difficult. I would suggest try not to use any such modules. Try adopting to indentations while learning itself. There are technical reasons why indentations are required. Indentation makes code more cleaner and readable.

Comment: You'll need to type `py -m reindent c:/yourfilepath` in CMD instead.

Comment: Try using a nice suitable editor that would help you tacking the indentation issues. And you may not need any such modules to reindent.

Comment: Yes @VincentRusso the environment variables are set.

Comment: @Reck offcourse,i have been trying to adopt,why not get to know  the reindent. At the moment in very new to python,IDLE is simple,i shall go for the an editor after some experience. .