# How to maintain tabs when pasting in Vim

Tags: python, vim, copy-paste, vi

I use the tab key to indent my python code in Vim, but whenever I copy and paste a block Vim replaces every tab with 4 spaces, which raises an `IndentationError`

I tried setting `:set paste` as suggested in related questions but it makes no difference

Other sites suggest pasting 'tabless' code and using the visual editor to re-indent, but this is asking for trouble when it comes to large blocks

Are there any settings I can apply to vim to maintain tabs on copy/paste?

Thanks for any help with this :)

**edit:**

I am copying and pasting within vim using the standard gnome-terminal techniques (ctrl+shift+c / mouse etc.)

my .vimrc is:

```
syntax on
set ts=4
if has("terminfo")
let &t_Co=8
let &t_Sf="\e[3%p1%dm"
let &t_Sb="\e[4%p1%dm"
else
let &t_Co=8
let &t_Sf="\e[3%dm"
let &t_Sb="\e[4%dm"
endif
```

I looked up that ts -> Sets tab stops to n for text input, but don't know what value would maintain a tab character

Comment: Are you pasting within vim, or from vim to another program, or from another program to vim?

Comment: What are your indentation settings? `tabstop`, `expandtab`, `shiftwidth`, `shiftround`, `autoindent`, `copyindent`.

Comment: I am copying and pasting in vim but using the standard gnome-terminal techniques (ctrl+shift+c or right-mouse-click -> copy)

Comment: @romainl see edit for current settings :)

Comment: Actually, using 4 spaces to indent is the recommended method.

Comment: is there a setting that will interpret my tab key as four spaces? I don't like the thought of hammering the space bar every time I need to indent

Comment: @WinstonEwert Wow, no war started after your comment, weird..

Comment: @Aus, for some reason the python community managed to pretty well standardise on 4 spaces, and its not a matter of war.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See `:h tabstop` for all the options and how they interact with each other.

These are good settings if you prefer tabs:

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set noexpandtab
```

With these settings, you hit `<Tab>` and you get `<Tab>`.

These are good settings if you prefer spaces:

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```

With these settings, you hit `<Tab>` and you get `<Space><Space><Space><Space>`.

Whatever you choose, you should not use your terminal key bindings for copying/pasting. Inside Vim, you should "yank" with `y` and "put" with `p` or `P`; optionally using a specific register like `"ay`/`"ap` to yank/put to/from the content of `@a` or `"+y`/`"+p` to yank/paste to/from the system clipboard (if your Vim is built with clipboard support).

As a side note, you should use the long form names of your settings as they are more readable than their short counterpart. Your future self will thank you.

Answer (score 6):

I was middle-click-pasting into a terminal vim instance. I have this in my vimrc:

```
set tabstop=2           " (ts)
set softtabstop=2       " (sts) Turned off with 0
set shiftwidth=2        " (sw)  Used for autoindent, and << and >>
set expandtab           " (et)  Expand tabs to spaces
```

I ran

```
:set paste
:set noexpandtab
```

and vim preserved the tabs that were in the source text. Without overriding my `expandtab` setting, vim was auto-expanding the tabs in the source text.

Answer (score 5):

[What romainl said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12585831/395321). Also, there are a few other settings that I find useful. Here is an excerpt from my .vimrc:

```
set autoindent " always set autoindenting on"
set smartindent " use smart indent if there is no indent file"
set tabstop=4 " <tab> inserts 4 spaces"
set softtabstop=4 " <BS> over an autoindent deletes 4 spaces."
set smarttab " Handle tabs more intelligently"
set expandtab " Use spaces, not tabs, for autoindent/tab key."
set shiftwidth=4 " an indent level is 4 spaces wide."
set shiftround " rounds indent to a multiple of shiftwidth"
```

In vim, enter `:h <setting>` for each of these settings to learn more about what they do,

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure your indent settings represent your preferred style, as romainl has shown in his answer.

If you must paste code from outside Vim (e.g. a selection from another terminal), the `:retab!` command can fix up the spaces to Tabs; for the pasted text the full command with the proper range would be

```
:'[,']retab!
```

Alternatively, you could try pasting with the `"*]p` command, which automatically adapts the indent to the cursor position (see `:help ]p`).