# Python reindent error

Tags: python, syntax

I "transfered" a python project from sublime2 to eclipse. Now I got a lot of indentation errors. I tried to us reindent.py script to correct this, but I got an error.

```
reindent -r /project_root
```

or

```
python -m reindent -r /project_root
```

results in:

```
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

I would like to reindent recursively.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are running on a system where you can easily install VIM, Alex Martelli's answer in this question is the quickest alternative to reindent that I have found.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024435/howto-fix-python-indentation

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some tabs and some spaces, it needs to be consistant.  If you do not have many files then running `python -m tabnanny <file name>.py` will help resolve which ones have the issue.

Comment: same thing with tabnanny: Indentation Error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level (<tokenize>, line 40)