# What's wrong with my python classes?

Tags: python, class

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my class code? When I executed it, the program just pop up "Indentation Error: unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

The following is my code:

```
class Student:

    totalStudents = 0

    def __init__(self, name, year):

        self.name = name

        self.year = 0

        self.grade = []

        self.attend = 0

        print("Add {0} to the classroom".format(self.name) )

        Student.totalStudents += 1

    def addGrade(self, grade):

        self.grade.append(grade)

    def attendDay(self):

        self.attend += 1

    def classAverage(self, grade):

        return sum(self.grade) / len(self.grade)

    def __str__(self, name, grade):

        return "{0} is a {1} grader studnet".format(self.name, self.year)
```

Comment: Paste your whole code to pastebin and share or use an editor that marks invisible characters with dots and lines (like SublimeText) to detect failing indentations.

Comment: i'd sugest removing blank lines between method definition and method body just to be on the safe side

Comment: works for me, using %paste in ipython.

Comment: do you mix tab characters and spaces?  That can causes problems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HOWTO: Fix Python Indentation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024435/howto-fix-python-indentation)

Answer (score 2):

While programming with Python you should take care of ;

- Don't use TAB character

or

- Be sure your editor to converts your TAB character to space characters

Answer (score 2):

This code works when I run it *in the current edit of the question* -- the question was edited by @KillianDS, and I presume he/she unwittingly fixed the problem by fixing the formatting.

Looking at the original edit, the problem appears to be on your first line after `class Student:`. The line `totalStudents = 0` is indented 2 levels in, whereas the line before it (`class Student:`) is not indented at all. EDIT: You also mix tabs and spaces, which causes problems.

Your formatting should look like this:

(Note: use 4 spaces, not a tab character! You should adjust your text editor so that it uses spaces, not tabs, when you hit the tab key.)

```
class Student:
    totalStudents = 0

    def __init__(self, name, year):
        self.name = name
        self.year = 0
        self.grade = []
        self.attend = 0
        print("Add {0} to the classroom".format(self.name) )
        Student.totalStudents += 1
```

Comment: I did not fix it unwittingly, markdown hides the tab/spaces issue (also with the original post), I just added an additional indentation.

Comment: In the original edit, `totalStudents = 0` was indented twice instead of once. That would cause an IndentationError too.

Comment: No, again, it's how markdown displays it, both use a single tab for that indentation.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're saying now. You just indented the first line, `class Student:` so that it would end up in the code block. I'm not so sure that OP realized he/she needs to put 4 spaces before every line in order to post it to StackOverflow, so I'm assuming that what he/she posted (without an extra 4 spaces on every line) is literally his/her code.