# Indentation not working properly in emacs for python

Tags: python, emacs

I am using emacs-for-python provided  by gabrielelanaro at this [link](https://github.com/gabrielelanaro/emacs-for-python).

Indentation doesn't seem to be working for me at all.

It doesn't happen automatically when I create a class, function or any other block of code that requires automatic indentation(if, for etc.) and press enter or `Ctrl + j`. Instead emacs says "Arithmetic Error".

It doesn't happen when I press `Tab` anywhere in a .py file. Again, every `Tab` press causes "Arithmetic error".

Also, when I manually indent code using spaces, I can't erase those spaces! Backspace-ing these indents also causes "Arithmetic Error".

This problem surfaces when I use the regular `Python AC` mode as well.

emacs : GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.10.7)
 of 2014-03-07 on lamiak, modified by Debian

Comment: Related to [this](https://github.com/gabrielelanaro/emacs-for-python/issues/118) issue maybe? Hard to say without knowing your configuration.

Comment: @vikramls How can I provide you with my configuration? I am new to emacs.

Comment: What I meant was the other packages that you have installed - can you run emacs without any init.el processing (emacs -q) and try selectively enabling packages? Did the issue I linked help?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. Here is my .emacs file : http://pastebin.com/EebZhxWP. I guess you can tell which packages I am using with this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check the value of `python-indent-offset`. If it is 0, change it `M-x set-variable RET python-indent-offset RET 4 RET`.

Emacs tries to guess the offset used in a Python file when opening it. It might get confused and set that variable to 0 for some badly-formatted Python file. If this is indeed the problem, please do file a bug report using `M-x report-emacs-bug` and the text of the Python file so that the auto-detection can be fixed.

Comment: Fixed it for me -- it was 0!  The first few lines were indented incorrectly (no indentation) and apparently that throws the python package off.

Answer (score 9):

It is related to this bug

http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=15975

The quickest workaround which I found was too add Jorgens Answer into .emacs file, add the following at the end of your .emacs file

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
  (lambda () (setq python-indent-offset 4)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you comment the lines related to auto-complete in your init.el?

```
; (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/auto-complete-1.3.1")
; (require 'auto-complete)
; (add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
; (require 'auto-complete-config)
; (ac-config-default)
; (global-auto-complete-mode t)
```

Comment: Done.Saved and evaluated buffer using `Alt X`.Restarted emacs and opened the .py file but the problem persists

Comment: Can you try disabling the epy-init.el line as well and see if `TAB` works in the python-mode that is bundled with emacs?

Comment: Invoke emacs like this: `emacs -q`. Then open your py file and try the `TAB` indent. Actually open your .py file, type M-x python-mode and then try the `TAB` indent.