# how to fix the "W293 blank line contains whitespace"

Tags: python, flake8

my python code produce the following warning message:

```
(1) \dir\file.py:8:1 W293 blank lines contains whitespace
this comes after commands[0] flake8 XXX
```

how do you fix the issue?

Comment: Make sure that any seemingly-blank line has no spaces or tabs.

Answer (score 17):

Using the same principal from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024435/howto-fix-python-indentation), you can use [autopep8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopep8) to automatically fix these. The syntax is ...

```
    autopep8 --select=W293 --in-place your_file.py
```

Comment: You can configure autopep8 to ignore certain error codes, either at the project or user level.

For example, you could add the following lines to a `setup.cfg` in your project's directory ...


`[pycodestyle]`
`ignore = W293`


See documentation for more info.
http://pep8.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html#configuration

Answer (score 4):

Simply delete the spaces, tabs, or other white space characters from line 8 in file.py.

Answer (score 1):

While in most cases it is best to just remove the extra whitespace from the lines, sometimes it is not possible. For example, when working with multiline strings where white space has some semantic meaning. Then, the best you can do is to add `# noqa: W293` to the line which ends the string. For example:

```py
my_long_txt = """
  For some reason
       
  whitespace required on empty line above
"""  # noqa: W293
```

This tells linters to skip linting the entire string for the W293.

Answer (score 0):

Blank lines should not contain any tabs or spaces. So remove the extra spaces as per PEP8.
Source - https://ayush-raj-blogs.hashnode.dev/making-clean-pr-for-open-source-contributors-pep-8-style