# Python: Indentation Errors

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, indentation

using Python I'm currently attempting Project Euler Problem #7 which asks to find the 10001st prime number, however when running my code I encounter the error

```
"File "<stdin>", line 3
    TestedValue = 2
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
Unknown error."
```

I'm assuming that isn't the only line which is facing that error but that's the first one that pops up, any idea what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks SO!

Code:

```
def PrimeNum(NumIn):
    PrimeNumCounter = 0
    TestedValue = 2
    if TestedValue == 2:
        PrimeNumCounter += 1
        TestedValue += 1
    else: 
        while PrimeNumCounter != NumIn-1
            for i in range(2, TestedValue):
                Prelim = 0
                if TestedValue % i != 0:
                    Prelim += 1 
                elif TestedValue % i == 0:
                    Prelim = 0 
                if Prelim > 0:
                    PrimeNumCounter += 1
        if PrimeNumCounter == NumIn-1:
            for i in range(2, TestedValue):
                Prelim = 0
                if TestedValue % i != 0:
                        Prelim += 1 
                elif TestedValue % i == 0:
                    Prelim = 0 
            if Prelim > 0:
                print TestedValue
```

Comment: Once you set the indentation you have to abide by it. You've got your blocks indented by 4 spaces or so everywhere except after that first if statement, where it's indented 8.

Comment: Whenever it gives you an unexpected indent, check the line above it. Also, make sure that your indents aren't tabbed. Do 4 spaces per level of indent.

Comment: You may have mixed tabs and spaces.

Comment: You also have a syntax error on `while PrimeNumCounter != NumIn - 1` line.  You need a colon there.

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist & others

I added those spaces only when submitting the question because the formatting instruction said to add four spaces when submitting code.  Sorry, new to this.

Comment: No problem!  The problem is that the code here _doesn't actually have the indentation error_.  If you copy it here and paste it into a file and run it, it will complain about the syntax error I mentioned above.

Comment: @CodyPiersall alright so should i just replace all tabs with spaces and edit my question?

Comment: I think you can just delete the question, really.  I asked some people in the Python chatroom and they agreed (or were at least quiet).

Comment: `while PrimeNumCounter != NumIn-1` should be `while PrimeNumCounter != NumIn-1:`

Comment: @CodyPiersall The site software converts tabs to spaces in the post.

Answer (score 3):

Your text editor is mixing spaces and indents. Python can only handle one or the other.

To fix,

> Use the reindent.py script that you find in the Tools/scripts/
>   directory of your Python installation:
>
> Change Python (.py) files to use 4-space indents and no hard tab
>   characters. Also trim excess spaces and tabs from ends of lines, and
>   remove empty lines at the end of files. Also ensure the last line ends
>   with a newline. Have a look at that script for detailed usage
>   instructions.

from [How to fix python indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024435/howto-fix-python-indentation)