# Python script (reindent.py) not working as executable in Windows7 from powershell/cmd

Tags: python, cmd, windows-7

I want to reindent a big python source file, and using `windows 7 64-bit`, `powershell`, and `pip`.
I installed `reindent` with
`pip install reindent`. I can see `reindnet` in `pip freeze`, and I suppose the package should work fine. 
But, when I do - `reindent -n \path\to\file.py`, I am always prompted to open a file, and the content of the file is always as follows -

```
#!c:\python27\python.exe
from reindent import main
main()
```

I am bit clueless and curious about this behavior. What exactly is happening here? How do I solve this?

I have set System Path variables with following entries-

```
C:\Python27
C:\Python27\Scripts
```

Also, I can run `python` and `<python_files>.bat` on `powershell` and `cmd`.