# Visual Studio Code indentation for Python

Tags: python, formatting, indentation, visual-studio-code

How do I enable indentation in Visual Studio Code?

I'm trying to learn Python (new to programming) and need auto-indentation. It worked with the first version I tried, but it doesn't indent after a colon (`:`) any more. How can I configure it to automatically indent?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can install the Visual Studio Code Python extension which will provide intellisense, auto-completion, code formatting, and debugging.

Here is more information on the Python extension, [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python).

Comment: Auto-indentation is now part of the extension, so it should just work out of the box.

Comment: Well, it's part of the extension, but it doesn't indent very well when there are continuation lines. :(

Comment: I agree with @JohnY, without proper indentation after a continuation line, editing is currently not much fun. I hope they fix this soon: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/481

Comment: I have installed the python extension in the marketplace but it didn't indent after ":" character. 

Python Indent worked well though based on Marjan Radfar's answer.

Answer (score 20):

As said there is the Python extension which now do it out of the box, but still don't do a great job, and an example is when you copy and past a whole block into a function or so. It just indents the first line, and that's not a good behavior. Here are two good helpful solutions:

- **indent a whole block manually**: **select the whole block**, and then click <kbd>Tab</kbd>. If you want to **indent backward**, you do it with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. That's it, and I think that can be useful in several places.
- **Python auto indent extension** (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hyesun.py-paste-indent). It solves the problem when pasting. Just see how it works in the link. Now about setting it up: **You need to set just one keybinding** for the command **"pyPasteIndent.pasteAndIndent"** provided by the extension. Once done, you will have your own shortcut to paste and indent automatically (I have set it to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>)

Here is *how*:
           - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the command palette, then write **"key"*, choose ***"open keyboard shortcut"**, and then the keybinding page open, which it's the nice interface for the **keybindings.json**. You can open **keybindings.json** the same way and by choosing **"open keyboard shortcut file"** (in place of just **"open keyboard shortcut"**). Give it a look if never have. But here I will go with the nice *interface*. Know also that you can open that going menu *File* → *Preference* → *Keyboard Shortcut*.

In the keybinding window, in the search bar, paste **pyPasteIndent.pasteAndIndent**, and then click the <kbd>+</kbd> button to add the shortcut and create the keybinding.

The image below shows well how it's done:

[image]

Comment: This didn't indent a block I tested with multiple levels correctly.

Answer (score 16):

I installed this extension: [Python Indent](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KevinRose.vsc-python-indent#review-details). It works very well.

Comment: Can you add more info what is the advantage of `kevinrose.vsc-python-indent`

Comment: It fixes a couple of indentation issues which the "standard" `Python` extension fails to address. Such as nested paranthesized expressions in a multi-line statement.

Answer (score 13):

Simple solution!

Click the tab size (may show "Spaces: 4") in the bottom right corner and choose *Convert Indentation to Tabs* or *Convert Indentation to Spaces* as per your requirement.

Answer (score 7):

I faced similar issues while editing. Select the lines of code you wish to intend and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> in Windows or <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> on Mac.

You can change the indent size in settings. Search for *tab size* in settings. I use two, by the way.

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 7):

For me, "Convert Indentation to Tabs" has worked.
To do that:

- Go to "Command Palette" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (View>Command Palette)
- Type in & select "Convert Indentation to Tabs" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: After you do this, you can go ahead and install the "Black Formatter" extension to help you format the .py files automatically. You can enable "Format On Save" in settings to help you out.

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar issues switching from PyCharm. The [Python Indent](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KevinRose.vsc-python-indent&ssr=true) extension, which is available in the Visual Studio Code marketplace, works perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

These three setting from [vs code website](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/editing#_formatting) helped me fix the indentation issue.

```
"python.formatting.autopep8Args": ["--max-line-length", "120", "--experimental"],
"python.formatting.yapfArgs": ["--style", "{based_on_style: chromium, indent_width: 2}"],
"python.formatting.blackArgs": ["--line-length", "100"]
```

And select one of them as the formatter using:

```
"python.formatting.provider": "yapf",
```