# How to indent/format a selection of code in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, indentation

I want to indent a specific section of code in Visual Studio Code.

I read *[How do you format code in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29973357/)* that gives shortcuts to indent the whole code, but it doesn't work when selecting a specific section of code.

I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> after selecting some line in my code, but the whole file is indented. I'm on Windows with Visual Studio Code Insider 1.8.0. How can I do it?

Answer (score 380, accepted):

> I want to **indent** a specific section of code in Visual Studio Code:

- Select the lines you want to indent.
- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> to indent them.

If you want to **format** a section (instead of indenting it):

- Select the lines you want to format.
- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to format them.

Comment: Shift + Alt + F can also be used for formatting ( Windows Platform )

Comment: Ctrl + ] or Ctrl + [ is conflicted with vim plugin.

Comment: If you are using the vim plugin, you can just indent using the vim command: > in visual line mode.

Comment: This doesn't work by default anymore on Windows. You need to set the shortcut for `Reindent Selected Lines` under _Keyboard Shortcuts_

Comment: Formatting a code block, plus increase/decrease indent short keys should be given a good exposure by default in VsCode under any menu, say the EDIT menu for example.

Comment: @RichardPovinelli comment about indenting while using the vim plugin is excellent and I would add to it that my usual way of indenting in vim land : mark the top line (as 'a' for instance) ; mark the bottom line (as 'b' for instance);  then (assuming my example marks) 'a,'b> will not work as it's not currently supported. This led me to think that indenting wasn't supported at all if you were using the vim plugin but, as Richard points out, that's not so.

Comment: Thank you !! VS Code user since ages, I did *not* know this :d

Comment: @SridharKritha: on my system (Win 10; VS Code 1.76.1) ALT+SHIFT+F is hard-coded to use 4 spaces per indent level/tab stop.  It ignores the tab and indent settings in the editor.

Answer (score 246):

- You can also indent a whole section (multi-lines) by selecting it and clicking
  <kbd>TAB</kbd>
- and also indent backward using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>

And of course for auto indentation and formatting, following the language you're using, you can see which good extensions do the good job, and which formatters to install or which parameters settings to enable or set. For each language and its available tools. Just make sure to read well the documentation of the extension, to install and set all what it needs. Exemple:  prettier is the most common used formatter for JavaScript and typescript. And it's widely used by all projects and code style requirements and setup. And in CI pipelines.

Up to now the indentation problem bothers me with Python when copy pasting a block of code. If that's the case, here is how you solve that: *[Visual Studio Code indentation for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143985/visual-studio-code-indentation-for-python/46899704#46899704)*

Comment: this doesn't work in VS Code for me, pressing tab while selecting text simply adds a tab where my cursor is

Comment: I think you selected only a portion of one line text. For that to work, you have too cases: you have selected multi-lines and in such a case it doesn't matter how much you selected, it will work.  The other case is to select the whole line where it will work too. If you select just a portion from one line, then the behavior is that a tab will be inserted in place of the selected text. I tested that in both windows and linux systems. Confirm if it's the same with you, or there is something wrong with your config.

Comment: MacOS Maverick (12) with non US keyboard: works like a charm. Thanks a lot. Happy 2022

Comment: It works on MacOS Big Sur with Italian keyboard

Comment: Works with french keyboard in Ubuntu..

Answer (score 24):

On OS X, choose "Document Format", and select all lines that you need format.

Then <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: This appears to do the whole file, not the selection :(

Comment: It works properly. I have a macbook air 2019, keyboard is different of my old ( I used to CMD + [ or ]). I have been look for this shortcut for the new keyboard. And, it is exactly what i was looking. It also works for a selection. Thks.

Comment: I was able to get this to work on a block of selected text (though I had to choose from an available formatter for my language)

Comment: The plug-in autopep8 needs to be installed

Answer (score 11):

This should be able to set to whatever keybindings you want for indent/outdent here:

Menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Keyboard Shortcuts*

`editor.action.indentLines`

`editor.action.outdentLines`

Comment: thank you! I was searching the keyboard shortcuts for `dedent` (which we use in our codebase), but it's `outdent`. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

(This works at least up to version 1.74.2, checked in Jan 2023)

---

On macOS Visual Studio Code version 1.36.1 (2019)

[image: Visual Studio Code version 1.36.1 (2019)]

To auto-format the selection, use ⌘K ⌘F (the trick is that this is to be done in sequence, ⌘K first, followed by ⌘F).

[image: Auto-format selection or document]

To just indent (shift right) without auto-formatting, use ⌘]

[image: Indent options]

As in Keyboard Shortcuts (⌘K ⌘S, or from the menu as shown below)

[image: Keyboard shortcuts]

Comment: Thanks for the "trick". I was losing my mind because the shortcut `alt/option + f` used to work!!! And suddenly it got replaced by ` ̰` character. So annoying!

Comment: It's strange that we have to find answers here for such simple shortcuts of a very popular code editor! VS Code shortcuts are not intuitive! :)

Comment: Haha, I guess we can ask Microsoft about that.

Answer (score 5):

F1 → open Keyboard Shortcuts → search for 'Indent Line', and change keybinding to <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Right click > "Change when expression" to `editorHasSelection && editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly`

It will allow you to indent line when something in that line is selected (multiple lines still work).

Comment: "F1"? Do you mean menu *File* → *Preferences*?

Comment: I meant opening command pallette. Forgot its name and I just remembered the default shortcut, sorry!

Answer (score 5):

As you've seen there are two ways to indent the code (this for Windows).

1. Reindenting the entire file

   <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

2. Reindenting only selected lines

   First set the shortcut for `Reindent Selected Lines`

   *Menu File* → *Preferences* → *Keyboard Shortcuts* → In the *Search in keybindings* type in `Reindent Selected Lines` →  Select it and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> → Type in your own shortcut, e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>, followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   Now select your code lines in the editor and use the shortcut set above, e.g. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd>, to automatically indent those lines only.

Answer (score 4):

For German keyboard layout, the standard settings are:

- Indent selection: <kbd>Strg</kbd> + <kbd>´</kbd>
- Outdent selection: <kbd>Strg</kbd> + <kbd>ß</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

On linux ubuntu: select text then `ctrl + shift + i`

Comment: Doesn't work. This formats the entire documen even if you have selected lines!!

Answer (score 3):

This is the way I had my code before formatting... [image]

Then I used the command like this... (Make sure to select the code part  that you need to format)

> `Shift`+ `Alt`+`F`

And I got the formatted code like this....

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On windows its "Ctrl+[" and "Ctrl+]" for indent and unindent [You can find rest of the shortcuts here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riyJG.png)

For mac, you can find the shortcuts here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

Comment: The [image you have linked here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riyJG.png) helped me to understand that "unindent" is called "outdent" in VSCode/ codium, so I could find it in the keyboard shortcut settings and assign a shortcut to it.

Answer (score 1):

For me on windows it was `Ctrl+¡` , *indent line*. It adds a tab at the beggining of each line.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the answers were not able to solve my problem too.

Just go for `fn+tab`

Welcome in advance.

Comment: Function keys aren't standardized. What keycode does this send on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

For me, using a mac in 2022 it was `CMD + ]` to indent multiple lines after selecting the desired indented lines.

Answer (score 0):

`Crtl + Alt + F` can also formate (windows)

Answer (score 0):

Windows - 2022

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can select text and press `TAB` to indent it.
You can also put your cursor on the begin of the line and hold `CTRL` + `ALT` and press up or down arrow to select multlines and when you selected the desired text you can press `TAB`