# How to indent/unindent a block of lines?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code, is there a quick way to change the indent of a block of selected lines like in Visual Studio? I can't find a suitable option under the Edit menu.

Comment: This feature is called `outdent` in VSCode/ vscodium, and when you search for it in the keyboard shortcut configuration you can assign a keyboard shortcut to it.

Answer (score 0):

Using Notepad++, you can select the lines you want then press Tab to indent and Shift Tab to unindent.

Comment: Do you mean using Notepad++ as an editor plugin in VS Code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492960/how-to-indent-format-a-selection-of-code-in-vscode-with-ctrlshiftf I think that should be what you want.

Comment: This is a question about VS code, not Notepad++.