# VSCode: Stop selecting the white space when tabbing a shortcut

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

In IntelliJ when you tab on a shortcut, the space after the shortcut is not selected but when you do that in VSCode it is, how can I change it?

Comment: I'm not 100 percent sure I understand your question but take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492960/how-to-indent-format-a-selection-of-code-in-visual-studio-code-with-ctrl-shift)

Comment: @nerap the indentation works for me but whenever I use tab for a shortcut the whitespace after the shortcut is  selected for example: I use the emmet shortcut for "id" which when tabbing it gives me id = "" and where the quotes are they are selected so I can't use constant abbreviations unless I move it with the arrows keys

Comment: Oh I see that's maybe how vs code is coded, so you won't change that, I never heard about a parameter that can change that, try to look for plugins maybe but your request is  a bit specific you might use key arrow for the rest of your life I am sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, go to settings and turn off "Editor: Insert Spaces"