# Why file read write functions don't work in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, file, writefile

[Whenever I try to run this code I keep getting error as shown on the terminal. Please help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3Hw0.png)

Comment: Code is not properly intended, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143985/visual-studio-code-indentation-for-python/46899704#46899704

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the code looks properly indented, it is giving IndentationError.
My guess is that you could be mixing spaces and tabs. It [is unwise to use a mixture of spaces and tabs for the indentation in a single source file.](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html). See also, [this other question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/197838).

There is no problem with having 2 tabs on each indented line, or having 8 spaces in each.

Answer (score -1):

You made to much SPACE after your "while"

**instead of**

```
while open('myfile.txt',mode='r') as f:
          f_con=f.read()
          print(f_con)
```

**DO:**

```
while open('myfile.txt',mode='r') as f:
  f_con=f.read()
  print(f_con)
```

Python is like that,only **press tab once**

Comment: Okay, Can I use shift+enter to run the code or should use Run from the menu?

Comment: This is incorrect. Python doesn't care how you indent, as long as you are consistent within each block. You can use a single space (though please _don't_: that's insane), or 19 spaces, or seven tabs... you can even mix them if you do it consistently, e.g. a tab followed by two spaces. None of these are good _ideas_, especially in Python, but they all work. Four spaces are generally a good choice as that's what PEP 8 recommends, but it's not mandatory.

Comment: I guess you right python is not my specialty I just remember writing a simple program with python and getting the same error for the reason I mentioned.. 

Comment: Configuring your editor to indent in a particular way and letting it indent for you is generally a helpful idea. Your advice to "press tab once" will work in most editors. But there's nothing visibly wrong with the first example. (If one line is indented with a tab and the other with eight spaces, though, it might _look_ correct but _be_ incorrect.)