# How to add 4 spaces indent to all lines in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, indentation, shortcut

I am using VS Code for Python development.

```
BranchList=['BD','WE','BB','GB','MB']
if lastMonth[-2:]=='01':
    month='Jan'
elif lastMonth[-2:]=='02':
    month='Feb'
elif lastMonth[-2:]=='03':
    month='Mar'
elif lastMonth[-2:]=='04':
    month='Apr'
........
```

If I want to use 'try:     except' to catch the exception(add a try: before the 1st row), all the rows below the 'try: ' should have additional 4 spaces indent. It's a very big manual work to add the 4 spaces indent for every rows. Is there any quick way to do it in VS Code?

Comment: By the way, `datetime` module already has functions to convert month integers into short strings

Comment: More specific QA to [`indentation in VS Code for Python`, incl. recommended extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143985/visual-studio-code-indentation-for-python/46899704#46899704) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you highlight all the rows and press `Tab`, they should all indent.  `Shift+Tab` will deindent.

Comment: Using  __press Tab to indent__ selection (or deindent with Shift+Tab) is a common keyboard-shortcut in many editors. Equally common would be __holding Shift__ and use cursor-keys (up/down/left/right) to select text or entire lines.