# Python correct indentation

Tags: python, indentation

I have a python script which contains the following part-

```
import csv
import mechanize

"""
some code here
"""

with open('data2.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        response2 = browser.open(surl+"0"+row[0])
        str_response = response2.read()
        if "bh{background-color:" in str_response :
            print "Not Found"
        else :

            print "Found " + row[0]
            s_index=str_response.find("fref=search")+13
            e_index=str_response.find("</a><div class=\"bm bn\">")
            print str_response[s_index:e_index]
```

When I'm trying to run this file, it shows there's an error in the line

> str_response = response2.read()

It says-

> str_response = response2.read()
>       ^ IndentationError: unexpected indent

I'm newbie in python and can not figure out what is the right indentation for this piece of code. Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: You're probably mixing spaces and tabs to indent.

Comment: mixed tabs and spaces?

Comment: Maybe you have mix of tabs and spaces in front of it. Copy all the whitespace from the previous line and replace the whitespace in front of str_response with it.

Comment: Yes, mixed tabs and spaces. You can see it in the question source. First three lines use spaces, then tabs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024435/how-to-fix-python-indentation

Comment: Yeah, I mixed up tabs and spaces. Didn't know the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I copied your code via the post edit mode, and as other have said, you have mixed tabs and spaces for your indentation.  In Python 3, you need to use one or the other, but not both.

Here is your original code with the tabs marked as `[TB]`

```
import csv
import mechanize

"""
some code here
"""

with open('data2.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        response2 = browser.open(surl+"0"+row[0])
[TB][TB]str_response = response2.read()
[TB][TB]if "bh{background-color:" in str_response :
[TB][TB][TB]print "Not Found"
[TB][TB]else :

[TB][TB][TB]print "Found " + row[0]
[TB][TB][TB]s_index=str_response.find("fref=search")+13
[TB][TB][TB]e_index=str_response.find("</a><div class=\"bm bn\">")
[TB][TB][TB]print str_response[s_index:e_index]
```

and here is the same code using 4 spaces instead of tabs:

```
import csv
import mechanize

"""
some code here
"""

with open('data2.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        response2 = browser.open(surl+"0"+row[0])
        str_response = response2.read()
        if "bh{background-color:" in str_response :
            print "Not Found"
        else :

            print "Found " + row[0]
            s_index=str_response.find("fref=search")+13
            e_index=str_response.find("</a><div class=\"bm bn\">")
            print str_response[s_index:e_index]
```

Comment: Thanks! I was completely unaware about spaces and tabs. It's working now!