# Why am I getting an error when I am trying to insert a while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here’s a problem that I was trying to solve:

> Ask the user for a string and print out whether this string is a palindrome or not. (A palindrome is a string that reads the same forwards and backwards.)

The code that I wrote was

```
print('Please type in one word which you want to check!')
num=input()

if (int(len(num))%2)==0:
    for i in range(int(len(num)/2)):
        if num[i]==num[-(i+1)]:
            if num[int((len(num)/2)-1)]==num[-(i+1)]:
                print('Yes the word is palidrome.')
                break
            else:
                pass
        else:
            print('No. The word is not palindrome.')
            break

elif (int(len(num))%2)!=0:
    for i in range(int((len(num)-1)/2)):
        if num[i]==num[-(i+1)]:
            if num[int(((len(num)-1)/2)-1)]==num[-(i+1)]:
                print('Yes the word is palidrome.')
                break
            else:
                pass
        else:
            print('No. The word is not palindrome.')
            break
```

The code is working perfectly fine.

The problem is that I have to relaunch the Shell every time I want to see whether a word is palindrome or not. So I thought that it would be cool to use a while loop.

I changed the code as follows ( by simply writing `while True` and leaving some spaces as shown below ) :

```
while True:
  print('Please type in one word which you want to check!')
  num=input()

  if (int(len(num))%2)==0:
    for i in range(int(len(num)/2)):
        if num[i]==num[-(i+1)]:
            if num[int((len(num)/2)-1)]==num[-(i+1)]:
                print('Yes the word is palidrome.')
                break
            else:
                pass
        else:
            print('No. The word is not palindrome.')
            break

  elif (int(len(num))%2)!=0:
    for i in range(int((len(num)-1)/2)):
        if num[i]==num[-(i+1)]:
            if num[int(((len(num)-1)/2)-1)]==num[-(i+1)]:
                print('Yes the word is palidrome.')
                break
            else:
                pass
        else:
            print('No. The word is not palindrome.')
            break
```

Python shows:

> Inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Why am I getting this and how do I fix it?

Comment: `num == num[::-1]` then you're done :)

Comment: `while True: txt = input(); print('Is Palindrome:', str(txt == txt[::-1]));`

Comment: Probably because you've used tabs in some places, and spaces in others. It's usually better to only use spaces - and 4 spaces for each indent level.

Comment: What editor are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

It means exactly what it says. You have mixed tabs and spaces in your source file. You can only use ***one or the other*** in each individual Python script.

Try looking here for a solution: [How to fix python indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1024435/1943571)

Comment: Yeah! I had to add a tab to every line in the code and then it worked! Is there some easier way to do that ?

Comment: @AaryanDewan In sublime text, there is. At the bottom bar, there is a button which says `Tab size: xxx` or `Spaces: xxx`. Do Ctrl+A. Click the button, then click on `Indent using xxx`.