# python while true wierd error

Tags: python, networking

I am learning python currently for a month now because I want to write a server for my GameMakerStudio 2 game, which doesn't support threading and I need a server to be written in another language to make this available. 
Anyways...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrtebUkUssc  -tutorial url

I was following this tutorial and unfortunately i get an error which is:

/home/borut/PycharmProjects/Server/venv/bin/python /home/borut/PycharmProjects/Server/Server.py
  File "/home/borut/PycharmProjects/Server/Server.py", line 19
    while True:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Process finished with exit code 1

And my code as followed on tutorial is:

```
import socket
import sys
from _thread import *

host = ''
port = 5555
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((host, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

s.listen(5)
print ('waiting for a connection')
def threaded_client(conn):
    conn.send(str.encode('Welcome, type your info\n'))

        while True:
                data = conn.recv(2048)
                reply = 'Server output: ' +data.decode('utf-8')
                if not data:
                    break;
                 conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
                conn.close()

while True:
                conn, addr = s.accept()
                print('connected to: '+addr[0]+':'+str(addr[1]))

                start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn,))
```

thank you for all your answers and tips guys!

Comment: You indentation appears random.  This will anger the Python Gods would demand uniformity in this regard.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024435/how-to-fix-python-indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your indentation is incorrect. By indentation I mean

> Leading whitespace (spaces and tabs) at the beginning of a logical
>   line is used to compute the indentation level of the line, which in
>   turn is used to determine the grouping of statements

[This link](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html) is helpful for you to see why indentation is important.

To fix this, format the code with an IDE. You can use this code instead, I have fixed indentation for you.

```
import socket
import sys
from _thread import *

host = ''
port = 5555
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind((host, port))
except socket.error as e:
    print(str(e))

s.listen(5)
print ('waiting for a connection')
def threaded_client(conn):
    conn.send(str.encode('Welcome, type your info\n'))

    while True:
        data = conn.recv(2048)
        reply = 'Server output: ' +data.decode('utf-8')
        if not data:
             break
        conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))
        conn.close()

while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print('connected to: '+addr[0]+':'+str(addr[1]))

        start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn,))
```

Answer (score 1):

Indentation is the most important think for Python since is the way you inform where begin/end a block of code.

Your first

```
while True:
```

is one tab ahead