# python beginner syntax statement if-elif

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm learning python, and I'm trying with a set of exercises, but I'm stuck on the next one:

```
     inp_1 = input('your score between 0.0 and 1.0')

        try:   
score = float(inp_1)   
if 0.9 <= score <= 1.0:
              print ("A")    elif score >= 0.8:
              print ("B")    elif score >= 0.7:
              print ("C")    elif score >= 0.6:
              print ("D")    elif score <  0.6:
              print ("Your grade is an F")    
    else:       
print ('your score is more than 1.0')  
    except:   
 print ('invalid input, please try with a number')
```

but I'm get the next message error:

```
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level on line 7 elif score >= 0.8: ^ in main.py
```

Comment: It's normal for new python users to get confused with indentation, please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29636895/797495) to fix the current script indentation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The indentation (= number of tabs / spaces in front of each line) is important in python. The code you posted isn't indented properly. A correct indentation would look like this:

```
inp_1 = input('your score between 0.0 and 1.0')

try:   
    score = float(inp_1)   
    if 0.9 <= score <= 1.0:
        print ("A")    
    elif score >= 0.8:
        print ("B")
    elif score >= 0.7:
        print ("C")
    elif score >= 0.6:
        print ("D")    
    elif score <  0.6:
        print ("Your grade is an F")    
    else:       
        print ('your score is more than 1.0')  
except:   
    print ('invalid input, please try with a number')
```

The first line is always un-indented. When starting a block (e.g. `try:`, `if:`, `elif:`, ...), all following lines that belong within this block are indented with 4 spaces more than the opening line. "Closing" a block is done by writing the next statement with less indentation.

Another example:

```
if False:
    print(1)
    print(2)
# prints nothing because both print statements are part of the if condition

if False:
    print(1)
print(2)
# prints 2 because the `print(2)` statement is not part of the if condition
```

Answer (score -1):

Your indentations should be like this:

```
inp_1 = input('your score between 0.0 and 1.0')
try:
    score = float(inp_1)
    if 0.9 <= score <= 1.0:
        print ("A")    
    elif score >= 0.8:
        print ("B")    
    elif score >= 0.7:
        print ("C")    
    elif score >= 0.6:
        print ("D")    
    elif score <  0.6:
        print ("Your grade is an F")
    else:
        print ('your score is more than 1.0')
except:
    print ('invalid input, please try with a number')
```

I think you didn't understand indentations fully. This isn't like any other languages. You need to make indentations correctly.