# how to fix TypeError in class

Tags: python

I have tried to run this code but i keep getting this error. I dont know what is causing the error. Please can someone help me out?

```
class Dog():
    """ A simple attempt to describe a dog"""
def __init__(self, name, age):
    """ Initialize name and age attributes."""
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
def sit(self):
    """ Simulates a dog sitting in response to a command."""
    print(f"{self.name}.title() " + "is now sitting.")
def roll_over(self):
    """ Simulates a dog rolling over in response to a command."""
    print(f"{self.name}.title() " + " rolled over.")

my_dog = Dog('willie', 6)

print("My dog's name is " +  my_dog.name.title() + ".")
print("My dog is " + str(my_dog.age) + " years old.")
```

Error

```
[Running] python -u "/Volumes/Macintosh HD2/python_project/python_work/classes.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/Macintosh HD2/python_project/python_work/classes.py", line 14, in <module>
    my_dog = Dog('willie', 6)
TypeError: Dog() takes no arguments

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.055 seconds
```

Comment: This code is not indent properly, does it look that way in your IDE?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how it looks in my IDE, but I can't figure out where the indentation went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python indentation is important,

`class Dog():, my_dog = Dog('willie', 6)`  This code lack in indentation,There are online indentation checker in case you find diffculty.

Comment: Please can you provide me any useful site for indentation checker. I am using Visual studio code and the indentation is giving me headache. Thank you very much.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024435/how-to-fix-python-indentation, Hope this StackOverflow answer can give good insights.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple- you have not indented anything after `class Dog()`.
Indent it, and everything should be fine.

```py
class Dog():
    """ A simple attempt to describe a dog"""
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        """ Initialize name and age attributes."""
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def sit(self):
        """ Simulates a dog sitting in response to a command."""
        print(f"{self.name}.title() " + "is now sitting.")
    def roll_over(self):
        """ Simulates a dog rolling over in response to a command."""
        print(f"{self.name}.title() " + " rolled over.")

    my_dog = Dog('willie', 6)

print("My dog's name is " +  my_dog.name.title() + ".")
print("My dog is " + str(my_dog.age) + " years old.")
```