# Whats is wrong with the if-else block?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
print("Guess a number between 1-10")
number = int(input())

import random
winning_num = random.randint(1,10)
numchance = 1

while True:
    if number == winning_num :
        print(f"You Won in {numchance} guesses")
        break
    elif number > winning_num :
        print("Too High")
        else:
            print("Too Low")
        print("Try Again")
        number = int(input())   
    numchance += 1
```

There is something wrong with else block 
it keeps on giving syntax error(invalid syntax)

```
print("Guess a number between 1-10")
number = int(input())

import random
winning_num = random.randint(1,10)
numchance = 1

while True:
    if number == winning_num :
        print(f"You Won in {numchance} guesses")
        break
    else :
        if number > winning_num :
            print("Too High")
        else :
            print("Too Low")
        print("Try Again")
        number = int(input())   
    numchance += 1
```

After editing my code it does'nt give any error but what i was doing wrong in the previous code?

Comment: As your error message tells you, there is no corresponding `if` to that `else`.  Indentation is critical.

Comment: Post the traceback showing the syntaxerror in the question.

Comment: elif and else indentations are incorrect... google how python handles scopes

Comment: This can be helpful                                
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024435/how-to-fix-python-indentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have invalid indentation in your `if-else` block. The correct structure should be:

```
if condition1:
    # code for condition1 
elif condition2:
    # code for condition2
...
elif conditionN:
    # code for conditionN
else:
    # code if none of conditions 1-N are met
```

Try to change you code to:

```
while True:
    if number == winning_num:
        print(f"You Won in {numchance} guesses")
        break
    elif number > winning_num:
        print("Too High")
    else:
        print("Too Low")
    print("Try Again")
    number = int(input())   
    numchance += 1
```

Comment: So arent elif and else if are same ? like elif  means => else : (enter} if ??

Comment: `elif` is the python version of `else if`. `elif` -> else with condition.