# what is the easest way to solve indentation problem in spyder 5.3.3

Tags: python, spyder

I am using spyder 5.3.3 for python coding. I copied the code from some sources,it works fine. But when I make edits in it, I get indentation error.

Comment: The easiest would be to understand the cause of the error and fix it by yourself. Do you know about the importance of [correct indentation](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_indentation.asp) in Python?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024435/how-to-fix-python-indentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of copy codes from different sources, I found that the easiest way to solve it by:
Go to Source --> Fix Indentation. this worked for me.