# How to fix:code indent should never use tabs in Vi

Tags: linux, git, vim, coding-style, vi

I have created a patch using git format-patch command and passing it to checkpatch.pl script which results in lots of code indent should never use tabs error.

But I'm not sure it should be fixed it ?

I'm using vi as an editor in unix environment .

Please advise me on how should I fix it?

Comment: It's a little ambiguous what part/output you're trying to edit, but you can replace all tab characters with spaces using `:%s/\t/    /` (4 spaces).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redefine tab as 4 spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878974/redefine-tab-as-4-spaces)

Comment: Thanks @timss but still see same error "code indent should never use tabs"

Comment: Oh right, sorry, I forgot that I had `set gdefault` in my config which always does `s//g`, i.e. all matches in a line is substituted instead of just one. Can you try with `:%s/\t/    /g`?

Comment: I just tried but I'm seeing Pattern not found: \t .

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar In that case it doesn't sound like your file includes any tabs. Again it's hard to understand where you're actually changing your text, but are you sure you're trying to edit the correct text? Do you find anything with a simple `/\t` search?

Answer (score 1):

The setting that controls whether `<Tab>` and autoindent insert tabs or spaces is

```
" spaces
set expandtabs

" tabs
set noexpandtabs
```

This works in conjunction with `tabstop`, `softtabstop` and `shiftwidth` settings (you most likely want to keep these equal):

```
set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4
```

You can also abbreviate all of these:

```
set et ts=4 sts=4 sw=4
```

Once your options are set, you can convert the current file's unwanted tabs to spaces (or unwanted spaces to tabs, if `noexpandtabs`) by issuing the `:retab` command.

Using a modeline in each file (`:help modeline`) or a project [editorconfig](http://editorconfig.org/) with the editorconfig editor plugin are advisable to avoid this situation in the future when sharing code with individuals with unknown editor defaults.

Comment: Thanks Amadan but it didn't help me as I'm still seeing error message like "code indent should never use tabs"