# vimrc tab behavior when noexpandtab and softtabstop is less than tabstop

Tags: vim, tabstop

## Questions

In the following example:

1. Why in the first line, a `\t` is inserted but only 4-col blank is displayed? Shouldn't it be `8` according to `tabstop`?
2. Why the two `<TAB>` hits in the first line and fifth lines have different results? (one is `09` and the other is `20202020`)

## .vimrc

```
set noexpandtab
set tabstop=8                             
set shiftwidth=4                                    
set softtabstop=4
```

## Text

I created the following text by first inserting 8 empty lines and then typing at the beginning of each line, so that there is no `shiftwidth` generated. (each 4-col blank below is inserted by hitting `<TAB>`):

```
1tab    done
2tabs        done
3tabs            done
4tabs                done
    1tab
        2tabs
            3tabs
                4tabs
```

## hex representation

Then I did `:%!xxd`, this is what I got (with some trailing newlines):

```
0000000: 3174 6162 0964 6f6e 650a 3274 6162 7309  1tab.done.2tabs.                                                                                                        
0000010: 2020 2020 646f 6e65 0a33 7461 6273 0909      done.3tabs..                                                                                                        
0000020: 646f 6e65 0a34 7461 6273 0909 2020 2020  done.4tabs..                                                                                                            
0000030: 646f 6e65 0a20 2020 2031 7461 620a 0932  done.    1tab..2                                                                                                        
0000040: 7461 6273 0a09 2020 2020 3374 6162 730a  tabs..    3tabs.                                                                                                        
0000050: 0909 3474 6162 730a 0a0a 0a0a 0a0a 0a0a  ..4tabs.........
```

### Related discussion

There are some pretty good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1878974/2160440) but I still don't understand what is going on in this particular case.

Comment: Actually it would have been better to ask this here: http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Wow, I didn't know there is a vi stackexchange before. Is it possible to migrate this post there?

Comment: I don't think it is [necessary](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251654/1771479), since the question is not completely off-topic on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

1. `softtabstop` is meant to be used that way, it will make your tabs appear a certain length even though they really are the length of `tabstop`

   > 'softtabstop' 'sts'  number  (default 0)
   >
   > ...
   >
   > This is useful to keep the 'ts' setting at its standard value
   >   of 8, while being able to edit like it is set to 'sts'.  However,
   >   commands like "x" still work on the actual characters.
2. As for the weird behaviour of inserting spaces at the beginning, I'm convinced it has to do with `smarttab` which is on by default and shifts instead of inserting a tab at the beginning of a line.

   > 'smarttab' 'sta'    boolean (default on) global
   >
   > When on, a < Tab> in front of a line inserts blanks according to
   >   'shiftwidth'.  'tabstop' or 'softtabstop' is used in other places.  A
   >    will delete a 'shiftwidth' worth of space at the start of the
   >   line.

Comment: "tabs appear a certain length" here do you mean `<TAB>` hit or `\t` by "tabs"?

Comment: Both if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: What do you mean by "even though they really are the length of `tabstop`"? I'm not using `expandtab`.

Answer (score 0):

IGI-111 answered your first question correctly, albeit maybe not clearly enough.

> 1. Why in the first line, a `\t` is inserted but only 4-col blank is displayed? Shouldn't it be `8` according to `tabstop`?

Keep in mind that TAB doesn't insert a fixed number of blanks, but advances the position to the next multiple of a certain number (if numbered from zero).

> What do you mean by "even though they really are the length of
>   `tabstop`"?

He must mean that TAB characters, when printed to your terminal, would cause the cursor position to advance to the next multiple of `tabstop` (8), while pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> in `vim` advances to the next multiple of `softtabstop` (4). If this next multiple of `softtabstop` isn't a multiple of `tabstop`, `vim` has to use spaces (0x20).

> 2. Why the two `<TAB>` hits in the first line and fifth lines have different results? (one is `09` and the other is `20202020`)

That's because in the first line you hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> after you typed `1tab`, i. e. you were at position 4 and to advance to position 8, which is a multiple of `tabstop`, a TAB (0x09) did the job, while in the fifth line you hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> at the beginning position 0 and to advance to position 4, which is not a multiple of `tabstop`, spaces are needed.