# disable gofmt in vim-plug in vim ide

Tags: vim, go, gofmt

How can i disable gofmt in vim-plug ide for vim?

Hello,
I'm using vim-plug as my vim based IDE for golang.
I've a very specific query. I don't want gofmt to do any unnecessary formatting for my code. I raised an issue with vim-plug on github but I was suggested that the issue is with vim-go.

I've my own `set tabstop=4` in my `.vimrc`.
I add header section to `.go` sources to help the reader understand what exactly the source file is all about. At many places in the code, additionally, I add more than 1 line in the code for cleaner segregation. Earlier, gofmt was modifying everything while saving a file.

By including following 2 lines in my `.vimrc`

```
let g:go_fmt_fail_silently = 1
let g:go_fmt_autosave = 0
I've gotten rid of unnecessary errors and formatting by gofmt to my .go
```

source files, respectively.

However, I'm not being able to disable gofmt from adding 8-space tab. Since I have my own 4-space tab, I don't want those 8-charater tabs added by `gofmt`.

So, I want to disable `gofmt` at all. Can someone please help me to disable `gofmt`?

Version information:
I use vim-7.4 on CentOS 7.2

Regards,
- sameer oak.

Comment: No you do not want to disable gofmt.

Comment: So `vim-plug` guys told you the issue is with `vim-go`, and you're asking here hoping to get a different answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of disabling gofmt, you could make it work how you expect. [This answer about tabs/spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1878983/151825) will be useful.

You need to set `shiftwidth=4` so that tab indents appear to be the same size as tabs.  There are no 8 space tabs vs 4 space tabs (tabs don't have a width, vim uses these setting to display the tab as 4 characters.

You really should reconsider fighting against gofmt, It will make reading the code much easier for anyone with Go experience.

Comment: thank you very much for the solution. i configured shiftwidth=4 and it solved my problem.