# vi:set tabstop=4 doesn't work outside vi

Tags: vi

I've created 2 files named tab1 and tab2.
For tab1, I've used normal tab which is using 8 space by default.

Meanwhile for tab2, I've changed it using `:set tabstop=4` command.

I've also tried `:set tabstop=4 softtabstop=0 expandtab shiftwidth=4 smarttab`

It was working fine in vi, instead of having 8 blank spaces, now I have 4 blank spaces for tab.

**inside vi**

```
123456789
    2   
~                                                                                                          
:set tabstop=4
```

However, when I view the files again with `cat` command, it seems like both commands didn't help at all.

Please let me know how to make this changes persistent even outside vi when viewing it using other utilities such as `cat`.

**outside vi**

```
123456789
user@host:~# cat tab1
        1
user@host:~# cat tab2
        2
user@host:~#
```

My goal is to have 4 spaces when using tab permanently even outside `vi` editor like this.

Please let me know if you have a solution for this. Thanks

```
123456789
user@host:~# cat tab1
        1
user@host:~# cat tab2
    2
user@host:~# 
123456789
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redefine tab as 4 spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878974/redefine-tab-as-4-spaces)

Comment: @yurikilochek, it's not duplicate. `:set tabstop=4` only works inside vi, not outside ... see my example above.

Comment: Read the accepted answer carefully, It explains how to make your TAB keypresses result in 4 spaces in actual file. `tabstop`  only changes how wide the tab character is rendered in the editor.

Comment: I was reading that before I post the question here, however I didn't see the answer. Please point it here if I missed it. Tq

Comment: [For indents that consist of 4 space characters but are entered with the tab key:
`set tabstop=8 softtabstop=0 expandtab shiftwidth=4 smarttab`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1878983/1554020). Or do you perhaps mean you want tabs to stay actual tabs but be rendered with 4 spaces everywhere? That is impossible without configuring 'everywhere' too.

Comment: `:set tabstop=4 softtabstop=0 expandtab shiftwidth=4 smarttab` wasn't the answer. 

I already tried that before I post it here. As I said in my post, it only works inside vi editor, not outside.

My goal is to have it with 4 spaces even when viewing it with `cat` command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152371/discussion-between-yuri-kilochek-and-charlotte-russell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the tabstop width in terminal with `tabs(1)`, e.g.:

```
$ tabs -4
$ cat tab1
    1
```