# How to view tabs/spaces and various tab-related settings in vim

Tags: vim

A great answer I read as to all the different type of tab-related settings in vim is in the answer here: [Redefine tab as 4 spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878974/redefine-tab-as-4-spaces). However, is there a way to actually see how those settings apply and affect a file? I have used something like:

```
:set list
```

But it doesn't really show me anything more than a bunch of `$` (linebreaks), and I don't see anything for spaces or tabs in my file. Is there a way to view all the space-like characters in `vim` so that I can play around with, for example, how `tabstop` might work and how `softtabstop` might work, and how they may all work together, etc.

Comment: `:set list` should show you tabs. Have a look at `:help 'listchars'` if it doesn't

Comment: David, just wanted to mention you’ve been asking a lot of qs about vim, and we do have a dedicated site with lots of experts at [vi.se]. Hope to see you there.

Answer (score 0):

There are four things in vim related to tabs:

1. tabstop
2. expandtab
3. shiftwidth
4. softtabstop

[Refer to useful reference of tab stops in vim](https://tedlogan.com/techblog3.html)

> **tabstop** Set tabstop to tell vim how many columns a tab counts for. Linux kernel code expects each tab to be eight columns wide. Visual
>   Studio expects each tab to be four columns wide. This is the only
>   command here that will affect how existing text displays.
>
> **expandtab** When expandtab is set, hitting Tab in insert mode will produce the appropriate number of spaces.
>
> **shiftwidth** Set shiftwidth to control how many columns text is indented with the reindent operations (<< and >>) and automatic
>   C-style indentation.
>
> **softtabstop** Set softtabstop to control how many columns vim uses when you hit Tab in insert mode. If softtabstop is less than tabstop
>   and expandtab is not set, vim will use a combination of tabs and
>   spaces to make up the desired spacing. If softtabstop equals tabstop
>   and expandtab is not set, vim will always use tabs. When expandtab is
>   set, vim will always use the appropriate number of spaces.

You can see current settings in vim by using below commands, in command mode:

```
:set tabstop?   
:set expandtab?  
:set shiftwidth?   
:set softtabstop?
```

You can set values for current session by using commands below, in command mode:

```
:set tabstop=4   
:set expandtab #if you want to remove expand tab, set noexpandtab
:set shiftwidth=4
:set softtabstop=4
```

Alternatively, if you want to make the changes permanent, you can make changes to vimrc file:

It is located in the below path:

```
~/.vimrc on Unix;  
$HOME/_vimrc on Windows
```

> For gvim, you can go to Edit -> startup settings to see current vimrc
>   settings and edit them.

You need to add a line to vimrc like given below:

```
set tabstop=4 softtabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 expandtab
```

Comment: right, I get that part, I mean how do I actually visualize what those four things are doing -- i.e., show a space or a tab or a newline or whatever in the file itself.

Comment: In vim,You can highlight space or tab, by searching for `\\s\|\t`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
:set lcs=space:_,tab:>~ list
```