# Inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Tags: python, indentation

```
def contains_sequence(dna1, dna2):
    ''' (str, str) -> bool

    Return True if and only if DNA sequence dna2 occurs in the DNA sequence
    dna1.

    >>> contains_sequence('ATCGGC', 'GG')
    True
    >>> contains_sequence('ATCGGC', 'GT')
    False

    '''
    b=False
    len2=len(dna2)
    i=0
    for j in dna1:
        temp=dna1[i:i+len2]
        if temp == dna2:
            b=True
        i=i+1
    return b
```

I am new to Python. The program pasted above gives me an error "Inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation" at line "if temp == dna2:" specifically. Can someone please help me out in finding out how the indentation is incorrect?

Comment: In above code, we can't see space, tab differently. You may want to post output of `cat -evt <yourfile.py>` which will show space, tabs separately.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It means you have mixed up spaces and tabs in the indentation. You have to fix that to be consistent with either tabs or spaces.

Comment: Anyone know how to fix swiftly with vim?

Comment: @jb1 Searching for “vim convert tabs spaces” would have given you [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/426963/216074).

Comment: We probably found it at the same time, thank you :^)

Comment: thanks, i added spaces in comment during copy paste

Answer (score 6):

If you look carefully at the lines

```
    temp=dna1[i:i+len2]
    if temp == dna2:
```

in your code, you will see that the "space" at the beginning of each line is "constructed" differently.  In one case it uses tabs and in the other spaces, or, if both have tabs and spaces then they are used in different combinations.

You can examine this by placing your cursor at the beginning of each line and using the right-arrow key to "walk" your way through the characters.  You'll see that the cursor moves differently on each line.

To fix, delete the tabs and spaces at the beginning of each line and re-insert them with the same characters on each line.

To avoid in the future, train yourself to use only the tab key OR the space key to indent, and consider setting your editor to automatically convert tabs to spaces.

Answer (score 3):

In my case Visual Studio code ..

Ctrl+Shift+P or View->Command Palette.

Type

> Convert Indentation to Spaces

press Enter.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a "good" IDE, it's best to set the tab key to make 4 spaces instead of a "tab", that way you have less problems, and it's good practice, for when you will work with other people.

Answer (score 2):

I was almost struct at this problem for quiet some time. I was using CentOS Ec2 and found out that you can:

```
vim <filename>
Press Escape Key If you're in write/insert mode
:set list
```

The spaces will be visible as *End Of Lines* such as `$` symbol.
It's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

According to the your Doc strings

your code:

```
b=False
len2=len(dna2)
i=0
for j in dna1:
    temp=dna1[i:i+len2]
    if temp == dna2:
        b=True
    i=i+1
return b
```

This much Big code can be simplified to one line

```
return dna1.find(dna2)>=0
```

Also if u are not good with indentations in 'vim' editor its good to practice in [IDLE3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE_%28Python%29)

Answer (score 0):

If you are copying and pasting code from another source, always copy and paste it on a normal text editor first, then fix the indentation after copying and pasting it in a code editor. This is an easy way to fix this issue.