# print function not working in python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

```
import threading 


class PrimeNumber(threading.Thread): 
  def __init__(self, number): 
    threading.Thread.__init__(self) 
    self.Number = int(number)

  def run(self): 
    counter = 2 
    while counter*counter <= self.Number: 
        if self.Number % counter == 0: 
            promptLock.acquire()
            if(prompt):print()
            print( "%d is not prime number" % ( self.Number) )
            if(prompt):print("number: ",end="")
            promptLock.release()
            return 
        counter += 1 
    promptLock.acquire()
    if(prompt): print()
    print ("%d is a prime number" % self.Number)

    #strange line
    debug_line = 1
    if(debug_line==1):
        if(prompt):print("number: ",end="")
    if(debug_line==2):
        if(prompt):print("number: ")

    promptLock.release()

threads = [] 
prompt=False
promptLock = threading.Lock()

def promptlocker():
    global prompt
    promptLock.acquire()
    prompt = not prompt
    promptLock.release() 


while True: 
    promptlocker()
    print("number: ",end="")
    input1 = int(input())
    promptlocker()
    if input1 < 1: 
        break 
    thread = PrimeNumber(input1) 
    threads += [thread] 
    thread.start() 

for x in threads: 
    x.join()
```

I am using this code to test threading in python3 
if i give an input 1000000099999963 and then 55 
as first input is lengthy and time consuming 
so it will be calculated in new thread and till then there will be a prompt to ask for new input , and then we can add new input and if it is easier to calculate then it with easily be calculated and printed .
and then when thread to calculate large number is finished then it will print its output .
so now i want that if code was asking for a number i.e. **prompt** is **True** then i want to print "number : " again .
i want output to be

```
number: 1000000099999963
number: 55
55 is not prime number
number: 
1000000099999963 is a prime number
number:
```

but the output is

```
number: 1000000099999963
number: 55
55 is not prime number
number: 
1000000099999963 is a prime number
```

when debug_line is set to 1 , dont know why the line

```
if(prompt):print("number: ",end="")
```

is not working

if i set debug_line to 2 , then the line will work

```
if(prompt):print("number: ")
```

Answer (score -1):

What error are you getting?

I changed the code to work in Python2.7
Here is my code:

```
import threading 


class PrimeNumber(threading.Thread): 
  def __init__(self, number): 
    threading.Thread.__init__(self) 
    self.Number = int(number)

  def run(self): 
    counter = 2 
    while counter*counter <= self.Number: 
        if self.Number % counter == 0: 
            promptLock.acquire()
            if(prompt):print()
            print( "%d is not prime number" % ( self.Number) )
            if(prompt):
                print "number: ",
            promptLock.release()
            return 
        counter += 1 
    promptLock.acquire()
    if(prompt): print()
    print ("%d is a prime number" % self.Number)

    #strange line
    debug_line = 1
    if(debug_line==1):
        if(prompt):print "number: ",
    if(debug_line==2):
        if(prompt):print "number: ",

    promptLock.release()

threads = [] 
prompt=False
promptLock = threading.Lock()

def promptlocker():
    global prompt
    promptLock.acquire()
    prompt = not prompt
    promptLock.release() 


while True: 
    promptlocker()
    print "number: ",
    input1 = int(input())
    promptlocker()
    if input1 < 1: 
        break 
    thread = PrimeNumber(input1) 
    threads += [thread] 
    thread.start() 

for x in threads: 
    x.join()
```

My output:

```
number:  1000000099999963
number:  55
55 is not prime number
number:  ()
1000000099999963 is a prime number
number:
```

If you're facing a problem with the print statement then you might wanna check your python version.

```
if(prompt):print("number: ",end="")
```

The above line raises SyntaxError in Python2. It's only supported in Python3
The equivalent code in Python2 is:

```
if(prompt):print "number: ",
```

If version is not the problem then you might wanna check this error
[Inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989171/inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-indentation)