# Invalid Syntax Regarding Number

Tags: python, syntax

I wrote this code, following a tutorial.

The number 640 kept getting an invalid syntax for some reason.

```
for bullet in arrows:
    index = 0
    velx = math.cos (bullet [0]) * 10
    vely = math.sin (bullet [0]) * 10
    bullet [1] += velx
    bullet [2] += vely
if bullet [1] 640 or bullet [2] 480:
    arrows.pop (index)
    index += 1
for projectile in arrows:
    arrow1 = pygame.transform.
    rotate (arrow, 360-projectile [0] * 57.29)
    screen.blit (arrow1, (projectile [1], projectile [2]))
```

Comment: What should it do: `bullet [1] 640`?

Comment: Please post the error massage.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he just forgot to write `== ` in the tutorial... The code there is formatted really badly.

Comment: You mean the spacing between the lines or the way the code was written on the website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If statement requires comparisons. Such as `==, <, >` or combination of them. You do not compare `bullet[1]` with `640` or `bullet[2]` with `480`.

```
if bullet[1] 640 or bullet[2] 480:  # no comparison
```

Based on your purpose, add comparison, like:

```
if bullet[1] == 640 or bullet[2] == 480:
```

Comment: Now I wonder if there's a particular format that I'm supposed to use because I'm getting an error that says there's inconsistent use of space. I couldn't even find the problem.

Comment: Indentation is important in Python, you can find some similar problems here in SO, and those post can help you, such as [“inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685406/inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-indentation)  or [Inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989171/inconsistent-use-of-tabs-and-spaces-in-indentation)