# How can I apply vimrc conf file in .py

Tags: vim

when I run

```
vim good.html
```

and

```
:verbose set et?
  expandtab
        Last set from ~/.vimrc
```

but when I run

```
vim good.py
```

and

```
:verbose set et?
 expandtab
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/python.vim
```

I want apply ~/.vimrc file in `.py`, not `python.vim`

Yesterday I all is fine but today suddenly path was changed

please someone teach me how can I change the path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this into your `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd VimEnter *.py set expandtab
```

or if you want to have the configuration of `.vimrc` to be executed after all plugins  being loaded - in case they have changed some settings -, you can add this line:

```
autocmd VimEnter * source ~/.vimrc
```

***Note:** It could have a side-effect depending on the content of your `.vimrc` because the latter actually will be executed twice (at the begining and at the end of vim startup) so you need to consider that.*

Concerning Plugins now, if they are logged in some specific folders like `.vim` or  vim installation path they will be loaded automatically unless you removed them or run some specific commands to be ignored.

Vim has also the ability to detect the type of file which is being edited, and this occurs when the option `filetype` is activated and probably this is what happened to you.

So typing `:filetype` will confirm that. Maybe you can desactivate it for some specific files if you wish. It is up to you !

---

`:help VimEnter`

> ```
>                                                    VimEnter
>
> VimEnter                        After doing all the startup stuff, including
>                                 loading .vimrc files, executing the "-c cmd" 
>                                 arguments, creating all windows and loading
>                                 the buffers in them.
> ```

Comment: thank you about your advice, and I try `autocmd VimEnter * source ~/.vimrc` and restart `:so %` so vim `.py` `:verbose set et?` show me `Last set from ~/.vimrc` but vim still tab use tab not spacebar=4 (ㅠ.ㅠ) ... and in `.py` `filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:ON`

Comment: I think I should desactivate `python.vim` or remove it but when I run `sudo rm python.vim` sudo has no permission Can I ask how can I remove `python.vim`?

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426963/replace-tab-with-spaces-in-vim). To know if it is a tab or space run `:set list` if you still see `^I` then you are right.

Comment: I have mistake @Meninx there is no `^I` in my eyes thank you very much! and you solved my problem thank you very much !!